# Chat type - scroll to bottom - angular 2

Tags: javascript, html, angular

Need to scroll to bottom automatically once messages are being added in a chat.

Tried AfterViewChecked method of implementing this, as suggessted in 
[[angular2 scroll to bottom (chat style)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35232731/angular2-scroll-to-bottom-chat-style][1])  - It works fine as it makes the scroll move to bottom. But when we try scrolling up as soon as we add a message in the chat, it is not allowing and it again pushes the view to the bottom of the chat

Please suggest a workaround on this.

Comment: Try this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/45367387/2349407

Answer (score 1):

The below code worked for me for my angular 4 chat application

My `component.html`

```
<div class="feedBody"  #scrollMe (scroll)="onScroll()" >
  <div class="feedList">
  </div>
</div>
```

My `component.css`

```
.feedBody {
  height: 235px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

My `component.ts`

```
scrollToBottom():void{
    if (this.disableScrollDown) {
      return
    }
    try {
      this.myScrollContainer.nativeElement.scrollTop = this.myScrollContainer.nativeElement.scrollHeight;
    } catch(err) { } 
  }
onScroll(){
    let element = this.myScrollContainer.nativeElement;
    let atBottom = (element.scrollTop+200) >= (element.scrollHeight - element.offsetHeight);
    if (atBottom) {
        this.disableScrollDown = false
    } else {
        this.disableScrollDown = true
    }
  }
```

I was using `element.scrollTop+200` because I wanted a behaviour where I should not compulsorily present at the bottom of the screen but can be a little top by 200px.

Hope it works for you.