# ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'undefined'

Tags: angular, runtime-error

I know there are a lot of same questions already posted in stack-overflow and tried different solutions to avoid the run-time error but None of them are working for me.

**[image: Error]**

**Component and Html Code**

```
export class TestComponent implements OnInit, AfterContentChecked {
    @Input() DataContext: any;
    @Input() Position: any;
    sampleViewModel: ISampleViewModel = { DataContext: : null, Position: null };
    constructor(private validationService: IValidationService, private modalService: NgbModal, private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {

    }
    ngAfterContentChecked() {

            debugger;
            this.sampleViewModel.DataContext = this.DataContext;
            this.sampleViewModel.Position = this.Position;

    }


<div class="container-fluid sample-wrapper text-center" [ngClass]="sampleViewModel.DataContext?.Style?.CustomCssClass +' samplewidget-'+ sampleViewModel.Position?.Columns + 'x' + sampleViewModel.Position?.Rows">
     //some other html here
</div>
```

*Please Note : This Component is loaded dynamically using DynamicComponentLoader*

After My trouble shooting I have identified couple of issues

First of all this child component is loaded dynamically by using DynamicComponentResolver and passing the input values like below

```
 ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.renderWidgetInsideWidgetContainer();

  }


  renderWidgetInsideWidgetContainer() {
    let component = this.storeFactory.getWidgetComponent(this.dataSource.ComponentName);
    let componentFactory = this._componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(component);
    let viewContainerRef = this.widgetHost.viewContainerRef;
    viewContainerRef.clear();
    let componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
    debugger;
    (<IDataBind>componentRef.instance).WidgetDataContext = this.dataSource.DataContext;
    (<IDataBind>componentRef.instance).WidgetPosition = this.dataSource.Position;

  }
```

Even If I changed my child component html like below I am getting this same error.Just add a angular ngclass attribute

```
<div class="container-fluid ds-iconwidget-wrapper text-center" [ngClass]="Sample">

</div>
```

My databinding and everything are working fine.Do I need to do anything on parent component?
I already tried all the lifecyle events in child component

Comment: how do you add `TestComponent`?

Comment: @Maximus as entry component

Comment: @Maximus I tried by calling  this.cdRef.detectChanges(); explicitly but not working

Comment: I've posted explanation why the error happens. Why do you need to update the `sampleViewModel` in the `ngAfterViewInit` lifecycle hook?

Comment: @Maximus Initially I am directly binded the datacontext property to the template and then I have tried this ngAfterContentChecked . In both cases I am getting the error.

Comment: what is unclear about my answer?

Comment: First of all move `this.renderWidgetInsideWidgetContainer();` from `ngAfterViewInit` to `ngOnInit`

Comment: @Maximus Thank you Maximus. My issue got resolved after move the  this.renderWidgetInsideWidgetContainer(); to ngOnInit. actually in angular official documentation https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader they are using ngAfterViewInit

Comment: @Maximus If you can add the above information in answer it will be helpful to others and I can mark it as answer

Comment: @JEMI, added that to the answer. You can now accept it. Thanks. To understand why they can use `ngAfterViewInit` and you can't understand my answer and all the details mentioned in the articles I referenced.

Comment: @JEMI, you're welcome) I've got many interesting articles, do check

Comment: @Maximus Sure. I am already your follower now. Your every article are in very depth.

Comment: Official guideline for the error from Angular - https://angular.io/errors/NG0100

Answer (score 76, accepted):

The `ngAfterContentChecked` lifecycle hook is triggered when bindings updates for the child components/directives have already been finished. But you're updating the property that is used as a binding input for the `ngClass` directive. That is the problem. When Angular runs validation stage it detects that there's a pending update to the properties and throws the error.

To understand the error better, read these two articles:

- [Everything you need to know about the `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` error](https://hackernoon.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4)
- [Everything you need to know about change detection in Angular](https://hackernoon.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-change-detection-in-angular-8006c51d206f)

Think about why you need to change the property in the `ngAfterViewInit` lifecycle hook. Any other lifecycle that is triggered before `ngAfterViewInit/Checked` will work, for example `ngOnInit`, `ngDoCheck` or `ngAfterContentChecked`.

So in order to fix it, move `renderWidgetInsideWidgetContainer` to the `ngOnInit()` lifecycle hook.

Comment: why are you updating the property in the `ngAfterViewInit/Checked`?

Comment: Actully it's not updating I am setting my input data to a viewmodel and finally all the properties are binded through this model like wrapper class. When I directly bind the @Input datacontext I am getting this same error. is there is no workaround to get rid of this error through any of the life cycle events.Let me try ngAfterViewInit/Checked mentioned in your answer

Comment: try `ngOnInit` or `ngDoCheck` or `ngAfterContentChecked.` If it's still not working, create a plunker

Comment: hmm..It's weird for me , as per my understanding it's pretty straight forward scenario. I am suspecting it's because of dynamic Component loader. Let me try to create a plunker.

Comment: I have tried all the life cycle events but unfortunately i couldn't fix the issue. but my question is updated by adding more points after my trouble shooting. hope this will helps you to get some idea.

Comment: i need a plunker

Comment: @Code-EZ Why is this chosen as the selected answer if you didn't get it to work? Or did you eventually get it to work?

Comment: @rooby, maybe because I explained the cause of the error and the exact solutions heavily depend on the application design

Comment: @rooby after moved to ngOnInit() ,it's worked. You can see my comments with Maxim.

Comment: For me work in ngOnInit only after i used a reference variable instead of a directory, like explaned here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48330760/cannot-read-property-viewcontainerref-of-undefined

Answer (score 167):

you have to tell `angular` that you updated the content after `ngAfterContentChecked`
you can import `ChangeDetectorRef` from `@angular/core` and call `detectChanges`

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

constructor( private cdref: ChangeDetectorRef ) {}   

ngAfterContentChecked() {
    this.sampleViewModel.DataContext = this.DataContext;
    this.sampleViewModel.Position = this.Position;
    this.cdref.detectChanges();
 }
```

Answer (score 27):

```js
 ngAfterViewInit() {
   setTimeout(() => {
     this.renderWidgetInsideWidgetContainer();
   }, 0);
  }
```

That is a good solution to resolve this problem.

Comment: None of the other solutions worked for my specific esoteric case so after a couple of hours I gave up and had to resort to this and it worked.

Comment: I didn't understand how but it worked for me too.

Comment: @FatihErsoy you can think of setTimeout() as putting something at the end of the overall JS event queue. So in this case, even with a Timeout of "0," it puts the code to run at the end of the events to run which means the code in Timeout will likely run after the Angular render code which is further ahead in the queue. Ultimately, setTimeout() feels like a hack solution, but when the Angular lifecycles aren't behaving as you expect and you're desperate to get it working then it's a tool you can resort to using.

Comment: I had this issue while loading a dialog component, with a list of checkboxes. By wrapping my code into the `setTimeout()` function, the dialog display is delayed long enough to get rid of that error.

Comment: Very sad that I have to use this, but it's the only thing that works!

Answer (score 21):

I was having trouble with .

> ERROR: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value for 'mat-checkbox-checked': 'true'. Current value: 'false'.

The Problem here is that the updated value is not detected until the next change Detection Cycle runs.

The easiest solution is to add a Change Detection Strategy.
Add these lines to your code:

```
import { ChangeDetectionStrategy } from "@angular/core";  // import

@Component({
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  selector: "abc",
  templateUrl: "./abc.html",
  styleUrls: ["./abc.css"],
})
```

Comment: Dangerous: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/23657#issuecomment-653939615

Answer (score 13):

If you are using `<ng-content>` with `*ngIf` you are bound to fall into this loop.

Only way out I found was to change `*ngIf` to `display:none` functionality

Comment: or can use [hidden]="!condition"

Answer (score 6):

Two Solutions:

1. Make Sure if you have some binding variables then move that code to **settimeout**( { }, 0);
2. Move your related code to **ngAfterViewInit** method

Comment: It depends as it moves your code to the event queue and it will get executed when the current execution finishes.
JavaScript is a single-threaded scripting language, so it can execute one piece of code at a time (due to its single-threaded nature) each of these blocks of code is “blocking” the progress of other asynchronous events. 
The settimeout code will be executed only when your current code finishes your execution.

Comment: hmm.. this fixed mine. I went to component and put all changes to bindings into a timeout of 0 secs and it works. is this a good solution or a hack? I am calling the method that changes binding value probably 2 times during the life cycle.

Answer (score 4):

```
setTimeout(() => { /* your code here */ }, 0);
```

I wrapped my code in setTimeout and it worked

Answer (score 4):

`*NgIf` can create a problem here, so either use display none CSS or easier way is to Use `[hidden]="!condition"`

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue trying to do something the same as you and I fixed it with something similar to Richie Fredicson's answer.

When you run createComponent() it is created with undefined input variables.
Then after that when you assign data to those input variables it changes things and causes that error in your child template (in my case it was because I was using the input in an ngIf, which changed once I assigned the input data).

The only way I could find to avoid it in this specific case is to force change detection after you assign the data, however I didn't do it in ngAfterContentChecked().

Your example code is a bit hard to follow but if my solution works for you it would be something like this (in the parent component):

```
export class ParentComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  // I'm assuming you have a WidgetDirective.
  @ViewChild(WidgetDirective) widgetHost: WidgetDirective;

  constructor(
    private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
    private changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef
  ) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    renderWidgetInsideWidgetContainer();
  }

  renderWidgetInsideWidgetContainer() {
    let component = this.storeFactory.getWidgetComponent(this.dataSource.ComponentName);
    let componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(component);
    let viewContainerRef = this.widgetHost.viewContainerRef;
    viewContainerRef.clear();
    let componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
    debugger;
    // This <IDataBind> type you are using here needs to be changed to be the component
    // type you used for the call to resolveComponentFactory() above (if it isn't already).
    // It tells it that this component instance if of that type and then it knows
    // that WidgetDataContext and WidgetPosition are @Inputs for it.
    (<IDataBind>componentRef.instance).WidgetDataContext = this.dataSource.DataContext;
    (<IDataBind>componentRef.instance).WidgetPosition = this.dataSource.Position;
    this.changeDetector.detectChanges();
  }
}
```

Mine is almost the same as that except I'm using @ViewChildren instead of @ViewChild as I have multiple host elements.

Answer (score 0):

#### RxJS timer()

Like others suggested you can solve the issue by placing your code inside a `setTimeout(..)` function. It will essentially move the execution outside the event-loop stack, and hence into Angular's next change-detection cycle.

RxJS has its [own timeout implementation](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/creation/timer) called `timer()` - it accepts milliseconds as an argument and returns an observable. Since we only need the execution to happen after the event loop stack is clean (and Angular has finished all its rendering calculations), we can use `timer()` without any argument (it'll anyway default to 0):

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    timer().subscribe(() => {
        // your code here
    })
}
```

JS event loop schema:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

PS: My error details vary slightly, in the sense that mine detected a change in `mat-focused` value from `true` to `false`.

During my research, I noticed that the error was thrown because I tried to bind the `SelectedIndex` property of `mat-tab-group` to the index of the selected item in a `mat-select` field inside `tab 1` of the tab group (code excerpt below).

HTML extract:

```
  <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <mat-tab-group animationDuration="500ms" [selectedIndex]="titleId.value">
      <mat-tab label="Tab 1">
        <mat-radio-group formControlName="titleId">
          <mat-radio-button value="1">Mr</mat-radio-button>
          <mat-radio-button value="2">Mrs</mat-radio-button>
        </mat-radio-group>
      </mat-tab>
      <mat-tab label="tab 2">
        ...
      </mat-tab>
      <mat-tab label="tab 3">
        ...
      </mat-tab>
    </mat-tab-group>
  </form>
```

Although my code worked as expected (i.e. switching tabs based on a selected item from the dropdown list), the error was pretty frustrating to be ignored. Unfortunately, no suggested solution here worked for me. However, I noticed that moving `mat-radio-group` outside the `mat-tab-group` component, fixed the issue.

New implementation:

```
  <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <mat-radio-group formControlName="titleId">
      <mat-radio-button value="1">Mr</mat-radio-button>
      <mat-radio-button value="2">Mrs</mat-radio-button>
    </mat-radio-group>
    <mat-tab-group animationDuration="500ms" [selectedIndex]="titleId.value">
      <mat-tab label="Tab 1">
        ...
      </mat-tab>
      <mat-tab label="tab 2">
        ...
      </mat-tab>
      <mat-tab label="tab 3">
        ...
      </mat-tab>
    </mat-tab-group>
  </form>
```

I expected the code below to fix the issue, but it didn't. Maybe I wasn't doing something right.

abc.component.ts code extract

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.cdRef.detectChanges(); /*cdRef injected in constructor*/
    }, 0);
  }
```

I still believe there is a better way to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

My best advise for debugging the error is putting a breakpoint in the `throwErrorIfNoChangesMode` within the `core.mjs` file. In this way, by analysing the parameters, you'll have all the information to find and address what's happening. Unfortunately, the Angular error message is not informative enough about what caused the error and where.

[image: dev tools screenshoot]

Answer (score -2):

Try this, to call your code in **ngOnInit()**

```
someMethod() // emitted method call from output
{
    // Your code 
}

ngOnInit(){
  someMethod(); // call here your error will be gone
}
```