# Cannot read property 'viewContainerRef' of undefined

Tags: angular, angular-directive, angular-components

I am trying to display a dynamic component similar (not exact) to the example in angular docs.

I have a dynamic directive with viewContainerRef

```
@Directive({
   selector: '[dynamicComponent]'
})
export class DynamicComponentDirective {
   constructor(public viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) { }
}
```

Excerpt from component code

```
@ViewChild(DynamicComponentDirective) adHost: DynamicComponentDirective;
..
ngAfterViewInit() {
let componentFactory = null;
                console.log(component);
                componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(component);
                // this.adHost.viewContainerRef.clear();
                const viewContainerRef = this.adHost.viewContainerRef;
                viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
}
```

Finally added `<ng-template dynamicComponent></ng-template>` in template

Comment: you probably need to add `this` here `this.viewContainerRef.createComponent`

Answer (score 42):

I had the same problem. You have to add the directive into the AppModule:

```
 @NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ...,
    YourDirective,
  ],
  imports: [
   ...
  ],
  providers: [...],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [components to inject if required]
})
```

Comment: solved my problem and wasn`t mentioned in Angular tutorial. Thank you

Comment: Wow. Great stuff. This must've been the accepted answer. Thank you.

Comment: Note with ivy this is deprecated.

Answer (score 36):

You can take this approach:
don't create directive, instead give an Id to `ng-template`

```
<ng-template #dynamicComponent></ng-template>
```

use `@ViewChild` decorator inside your component class

```
@ViewChild('dynamicComponent', { read: ViewContainerRef }) myRef

ngAfterViewInit() {
    const factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(component);
    const ref = this.myRef.createComponent(factory);
    ref.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
}
```

Comment: This worked, so thanks, but I'm curious as to WHY it works.  My directive selector was correct, but for whatever reason could not be found.  When I switched to ID selector it picked it right up.

Comment: It's not clear what `component` is supposed to refer to in `resolveComponentFactory(component)`

Comment: This worked for me..but how do you pass data to the component being dynamically created?

Comment: @Kingsley You can set properties on the component instance like this: `ref.instance.someInputData = data`

Comment: const viewContainerRef = this.adHost.viewContainerRef; This somehow doesn't work with a directive. When using a reference variable we should just call const viewContainerRef = this.adHost;
viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory); works just fine.

Answer (score 18):

In Angular 8 my fix was:

```js
@ViewChild('dynamicComponent', {static: true, read: ViewContainerRef}) container: ViewContainerRef;
```

Comment: that fixed my issue

Comment: They mention it in their update guide (https://update.angular.io/#7.0:8.0l3) and Static query migration guide (https://angular.io/guide/static-query-migration), but your example makes it even clearer.

Comment: Angular 11, same issue with the ng-if, solved by adding similar line ```@ViewChild('dynamicComponent', {static: true}) container: ViewContainerRef;```

Answer (score 9):

I ran into this problem as well and the reason was that the location which I wanted to load my component dynamicly into was inside an ng-if that was hidden initially.

```
<div *ngIf="items">
   <ng-template appInputHost></ng-template>
</div>

@ViewChild(InputHostDirective, { static: true }) inputHost: InputHostDirective;
```

Moving the ng-template to outside the ng-if solved the problem.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, it was Angular 9 and the directive's selector was inside `*ngIf`. The solution I used was:

```
@ViewChild(ExampleDirective, {static: false}) exampleDirectiveHost: ExampleDirective;
```

Mark `static` is false due to reasons defined here [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild)

The other thing I did was use

```
ngAfterViewInit(){
   const viewContainerRef = this.exampleDirectiveHost.viewContainerRef;;
}
```

Comment: My issue was on ngOninit, the view container ref was undefined. once moved to ngAfterViewInit() it was working fine.

Answer (score 2):

Noted that I face the same problem if directive selector (dynamicComponent in this case) is at :

1. first element of the component
2. parent element with *ngIf condition

Hence, I avoid it by put it inside at non-root tag in the component html & load component to viewContainerRef only when the condition match.

Comment: I was suffering from undefined error of `viewContainerRef` element, spending some hours to find what was the problem. Finally, saw your answer and just instantiated empty object instead of checking it with *ngIf and viola! Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

**Template HTML file:**

```
<ng-template #containerToHostDynamicallyInjectedComponents"></ng-template>
```

**TS file**

private componentRef: ComponentRef<COMPONENT_NAME_TO_CREATE> = null;

@ViewChild('containerToHostDynamicallyInjectedComponents', {read: ViewContainerRef}) hostContainer: ViewContainerRef;

````
constructor(private componentFactoryResolver:ComponentFactoryResolver) {}


ngOnInit() {

 const componentFactory = 
    this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(<COMPONENT_NAME_TO_CREATE>);
    this.hostContainer.clear(); // CLEAR ANY INJECTED COMPONENT IF EXISTED.
    this.componentRef = this.hostContainer.createComponent(componentFactory);

}

```
````

- this.componentRef: => stores reference of dynamically created component to access component public properties and methods and even subscribe to event emitter

ACESSS COMPONENT PROPERTIES AND METHODS USING:

```
 this.componentRef.instance.<PROPERTY_NAME>
 this.componentRef.instance.<METHOD_NAME>();
```

YOU CAN EVEN SUBSCRIBE TO @Output EVENT EMITTERS

```
this.componentRef.instance.<OUTPUT_PROPERTY_NAME>
.pipe(
  take(1)
)
.subscribe(response => console.log(response));
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem might also be that the selector of the `viewRef` (`dynamicComponent` in this example) does not match the one specified in the template of the component which uses the `componentFactoryResolver`.

Answer (score 0):

I just added the viewContainerRef stuff in the afterViewInit() cicle instead of the onInit() cicle, it worked for me :T

I am using Angular v11

```
 ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        const viewContainerRef = this.exampleHost.viewContainerRef;
        viewContainerRef.clear();
        const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(ExampleEntryComponent);
        viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, there was a typo in the directive selector on the `ng-template`, and thus it did not match with the one declared in the directive, thus ViewContainerRef was `undefined`. Simple cause, it was easy to overlook at  first glance, as the error message may suggest having a more complex problem.

Answer (score -1):

You see this error when the directive does not construct. You can set a breakpoint on the directive's constructor and check if the breakpoint ever hits. If not, that means that you are not loading the directive correctly. Then you can check that your component that is loading the directive it is properly adding the directive into the template.