# How to import automapper-ts in Angular 9

Tags: angular, angular9

So I was updating a project from Angular 7 to Angular 9 and once I was done with the update the Automapper-ts is throwing error.

It was working perfectly fine with Angular 7.
I am importing like this

import * as automapper from 'automapper-ts';

but now when I try to build it says

'automapper.d.ts' is not a module.

I have followed the exact steps mention on the Github page for Automapper-ts

I am kind of stuck now.

I am new to Angular so please bear with me if I am making a silly mistake :)

[terminal output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZsKQv.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**
Just add this to the top of your file:

```
import 'automapper-ts';
```

Comment: Yes i thought so and tried this myself and was able to build the project successfully but then I face a different error. Not sure whether it is linked to automapper-ts or not.

Comment: vendor.56b6382590af3f372544.js:formatted:42959 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'viewContainer' of undefined
    at e.t._forceRenderHeaderRows (vendor.56b6382590af3f372544.js:formatted:1379)
    at e.t.ngAfterContentChecked (vendor.56b6382590af3f372544.js:formatted:1135)
    at We (vendor.56b6382590af3f372544.js:formatted:42612)
    at Ve (vendor.56b6382590af3f372544.js:formatted:42603)
    at He (vendor.56b6382590af3f372544.js:formatted:42588)
    at ti (vendor.56b6382590af3f372544.js:formatted:43701)
    at vendor.56b6382590af3f372544.js:formatted:43691
    ... continued

Comment: create a new post on stackoverflow with the specific error so I can help you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48330760/cannot-read-property-viewcontainerref-of-undefined

Comment: yes sure, i'll do that in some time and will tag you along.