# Angular Material Stepper Component For Each Step

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a `angular material linear stepper` each step is a separate `angular component` containing a `form` which needs `validation`

The validation simply just isn't working. I can progress through to the next step without completing the form.

To illustrate what I mean I have created a condensed version on stackblitz.

The main things to look at (I think) is the `create-profile.component.html`

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper linear #stepper>
    <mat-step [stepControl]="frmStepOne">
        <ng-template matStepLabel>Step One Details</ng-template>
        <step-one-component></step-one-component>
    </mat-step>
    <mat-step [stepControl]="frmStepTwo">
        <ng-template matStepLabel>Step Two Details</ng-template>
        <step-two-component></step-two-component>
    </mat-step>
    <mat-step [stepControl]="frmStepThree">
        <ng-template matStepLabel>Step Three Details</ng-template>
        <step-three-component></step-three-component>
    </mat-step>
</mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

And each `step-X-component`

Here is the stackblitz. 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vpoj5j

Comment: I checked your stackblitz. linear mode is not working there.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The problem is in your `CreateProfileComponent`:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'create-profile-component',
    templateUrl: './create-profile.component.html'
})
export class CreateProfileComponent {

    frmStepOne: FormGroup;
    frmStepTwo: FormGroup;
    frmStepThree: FormGroup;

    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

}
```

There is no relation between your defined FormGroups in `CreateProfileComponent` and your stepper components. You tried to extend every `StepComponent` with `CreateProfileComponent`, but with this approach every `StepComponent` has its own instance of `CreateProfileComponent` and so their own `FormGroup` declaration.

To solve your problem you can declare template variables for every `StepComponent` in your html (starting with `#`) and pass the formControl to `[stepControl]`:

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper linear #stepper>
    <mat-step [stepControl]="step1.frmStepOne">
        <ng-template matStepLabel>Step One Details</ng-template>
        <step-one-component #step1></step-one-component>
    </mat-step>
    <mat-step [stepControl]="step2.frmStepTwo">
        <ng-template matStepLabel>Step Two Details</ng-template>
        <step-two-component #step2></step-two-component>
    </mat-step>
    <mat-step [stepControl]="step3.frmStepThree">
        <ng-template matStepLabel>Step Three Details</ng-template>
        <step-three-component #step3></step-three-component>
    </mat-step>
</mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

Or you leave your html as it is and work with `ViewChild()` (my preferred approach):

```
@Component({
    selector: 'create-profile-component',
    templateUrl: './create-profile.component.html'
})

export class CreateProfileComponent {

    @ViewChild(StepOneComponent) stepOneComponent: StepOneComponent;
    @ViewChild(StepTwoComponent) stepTwoComponent: StepTwoComponent;
    @ViewChild(StepTwoComponent) stepThreeComponent: StepThreeComponent;

    get frmStepOne() {
       return this.stepOneComponent ? this.stepOneComponent.frmStepOne : null;
    }

    get frmStepTwo() {
       return this.stepTwoComponent ? this.stepTwoComponent.frmStepTwo : null;
    }

    get frmStepThree() {
       return this.stepThreeComponent ? this.stepThreeComponent.frmStepThree : null;
    }

}
```

Either way there is no need to extend your `StepComponents` with `CreateProfileComponent` and it doesn't make any sense.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'step-x-component',
    templateUrl: './step-x.component.html',
})
export class StepXComponent {

    public frmStepX: FormGroup;

    constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.frmStepX = this.formBuilder.group({
            name: ['', Validators.required]
        });

    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the clear explanation. You're right, there wasn't really any need to extend CreateProfile component. Again, thanks for the solution.

Comment: I had to use the "ViewChild" approach, because the other one triggered a "ExpressionHasChangedAfterCheck" error! Although it worked, it may cause problems in the future (or not if they solve in the core this issue). Anyway thanks for this (I upped yesterday)

Comment: Moving the frmStepX declaration into the constructor solves the problem.

Comment: just a note: I was getting `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'undefined'. Current value: '[object Object]'.` error and solved it by initialising individual step components' forms in the constructor.

Comment: Just create the form group in the constructor `this.form = new FormGroup({});`

Comment: Shining example of what a SO response should be.  Well explained and an elegant, simple solution.  Helped me with my issues as well.  Nice work @SplitterAlex

Comment: @splitterAlex, I've got the forms split up in separate components but the linear property is ignored and the valid status of the children are not being considered when using matStepperNext/matStepperPrevious.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: @ustad Can you prepare a small and simple demo of your problem on Stackblitz? That way it makes it easy for me to help you.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @SplitterAlex, I did not include the step component references in the template (#step1, #step2) as I was a bit confused when you said, "Or you leave your html as it is...".  My bad :)    Works perfectly now and my code is much easier to maintain.  Thanks again.

Comment: moving the form initialization from onInit to constructor does not solve the issue for me :(

Comment: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'undefined'. Current value: '[object Object]'. this error solved by this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45467881/expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-expression-has-changed-after-it-was

Answer (score 0):

Your stepper and forms components works on different form objects. You need to set super's forms objects in step component's `ngOnInit()`

```
ngOnInit() {
    super.frmStepTwo = this.formBuilder.group({
        address: ['', Validators.required]
    });
}
```

instead

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.frmStepTwo = this.formBuilder.group({
        address: ['', Validators.required]
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To have a mat-stepper with each step as its own component, create the buttons to traverse through the stepper outside the component and show/hide the traversal buttons based on form validation done inside the individual component and expose the form info to the parent stepper.

For Example:

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper  #stepper linear  iseditable>
<mat-step 
 [stepControl]="firstFormGroup" 
 [completed]="primaryIsTrue"
 >
  <app-primary-settings  
  (formIsValid)="formValidity($event)"></app-primary-settings>

  <button mat-button matStepperNext 
   *ngIf="primaryIsTrue">
    Next
   </button>
</mat-step>

</mat-horizontal-stepper>
```