# I am not able to load component dynamically in every steps in Angular 7 material stepper

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I am trying to load components and steps  dynamically on each step in Angular material stepper but I am only able to do on the first step only my requirement is like if one component has 3 steps then it should load three steps dynamically with three different component and each step one component should load once we go to next step then second component should load.

How can I to load dynamic component on each step if we click next button? What I have done till now:

1) On each navigation button click, I am passing query parameter and according to query params value I am loading Components and depends upon the component requirement I am loading steps dynamically it is working perfectly even I am able to load dynamic component on the first step

2) I am not able to load components on each step

3) SharedWizard Component is my stepper component and all dynamic component load method and in landing component, I have a navigation button.

4) In the shared wizard, I am using the JSON object for component and steps

5) `createComponent()` is my function for loading component dynamically

Find below my code the link:

[`Updated_Stackblitz_Example`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mjkhdb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcore%2FsharedWizard%2Fsharedwizard.component.ts)

Comment: Please help any one how to load component dynamically on each step in angular material stepper.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular Material Stepper Component For Each Step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48498966/angular-material-stepper-component-for-each-step)

Comment: Check this:https://stackoverflow.com/q/48498966/7124761

Comment: I want  to load components and steps both dynamically. my requirement is if DataSource component have 2 steps then it should load only two steps and if DtaSourceAccess has four steps then it should load four steps and on each steps respective components should load.

Comment: Can any one help me according to my requirement