# ViewChild with Stepper ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError Angular 8

Tags: angular, angular-material, viewchild

I'm trying to use ViewChild to get a child component's attribute for the Stepper [completed] property, but I can't figure out how to fix the "ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'completed: null'. Current value: 'completed: false'".

I followed this answer: [Angular Material Stepper Component For Each Step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48498966/angular-material-stepper-component-for-each-step#comment86865807_48499711)

```
parent component .ts
@ViewChild(FirstStepComponent, {static: false}) firstStepComp: FirstStepComponent;

get firstStepCompleted() {
    return this.firstStepComp ? this.firstStepComp.completed : null;
}

parent component .html
<mat-step [completed]="firstStepCompleted">
  <app-first-step>
  </app-first-step>
</mat-step>

in the child component .ts
completed: boolean = false;
```

Comment: are you tried with this `[completed]="firstStepComp?.completed"`

Comment: I have, same problem

Answer (score 1):

Before all I have to tell you that this error is thrown only in `dev` mode. If you call `enableProdMode()` when `bootstrapping` the app, it won't get thrown. This doesnt happens mainly in `dev` mode because after every save angular will run its rounds of `changeDetection` cycles and with it double checks the `bindings` of it weather if it has changed from the initial.

**Key Idea :** Anything that changes a `bindings` needs to go through a cycle of `changeDetection`

> For furthermore elaboration on this issue please go through @drew
>   moore's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34364880/expression-has-changed-after-it-was-checked).