# Angular Material Stepper with Separate Component for each step - ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular9, angular-material-stepper

I have a material stepper with forms in each step of the stepper. There, each step should be controlled by the form associated with it.

Even though this question has already been asked in SO, the answers to those questions do not resolve my issue. Hence I am asking.

**Parent HTML**

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper linear #stepper>
    <mat-step [stepControl]="frmStepOne">
        <ng-template matStepLabel>Step One Details</ng-template>
        <app-first-step #stepOne></app-first-step>
    </mat-step>
    <mat-step [stepControl]="frmStepTwo">
        <ng-template matStepLabel>Step Two Details</ng-template>
        <app-second-step #stepTwo></app-second-step>
    </mat-step>
</mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

**In my parent component, I have following.**

```
@ViewChild('stepOne') stepOneComponent: FirstStepComponent;
@ViewChild('stepTwo') stepTwoComponent: SecondStepComponent;


get frmStepOne() {
    return this.stepOneComponent ? this.stepOneComponent.frmStepOne : null;
}

get frmStepTwo() {
    return this.stepTwoComponent ? this.stepTwoComponent.frmStepTwo : null;
}
```

**My Child class Component**

```
frmStepOne: FormGroup;

constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {

    this.frmStepOne = this.formBuilder.group({
      name: ['', Validators.required]
    });
}
```

**Child Class HTML**

```
<mat-card>

  <form [formGroup]="frmStepOne">

    <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput formControlName="name" matInput placeholder="Name" required>
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-card-actions>
      <button mat-raised-button matStepperNext class="nav-btn pull-right">Next</button>
    </mat-card-actions>

  </form>

</mat-card>
```

Now, when I run the app, In the console, I see following.

> ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression
> has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'stepControl: null'.
> Current value: 'stepControl: [object Object]'.

As I mentioned before, there are discussions on the same in SO. For example, answer and the comments of the following linked question suggest to  move form initialization to the constructor instead of having it in the onInit. I have done so.

[Angular Material Stepper Component For Each Step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48498966/angular-material-stepper-component-for-each-step)

However, I still get the error.

This is my project on Stackblitz -  https://stackblitz.com/github/vigamage/stepper-component-wise

Can someone suggest how to get rid of the issue?

Thank you..

Comment: also please modify the header of your question.. it has nothing to do with Angular material and its stepper and more important, we need to thank Angular for showing us what's wrong with our code in development mode because in production you won't get this error.

Comment: please find the solution I offered. I modified your code for the error to disappear [link to the solution](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-jdw2yr?file=src/app/app.component.ts) there is no need to use change detection.. you owe me a change detection :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change the variable that causes this error to an `Observable` and `pipe` it with the `delay(0)` `operator`

here is a [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-jdw2yr?file=src/app/app.component.ts) to a working solution - no error and no need to use change detection.

here is an example

Let's say that I'm using a variable `name` of type `string` inside my `html` template and it causes  the error mentioned above.

```
<div>{{ name }}</div> // BOOM ERROR why?
```

because at first `name` was something and it was changed after angular already checked it.

so to solve this.. first change `name` to an `Observable` like `name$`

```
name$: Observable<string>; // name$ replaces name    

private myName$ = new BehaviorSubject<string>("");
myNameListener$: Observable<string> = this.myName$.asObservable();
myName(name: string) {
    this.myName$.next(name)
}
```

now in `ngOnInit()` just listen to that Observable

```
ngOnInit() {

    this.name$ = this.myNameListener$.pipe(
        delay(0)
    )

}
```

subscribe to that `Observable` in your `html` template using the `async` pipe

```
<div *ngIf=" (name$ | async) as name ">{{ name }}</div> // render your variable
```

now pass your **actual data** to the observable where ever you want.

```
this.myName(data);
```

here is a [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-jdw2yr?file=src/app/app.component.ts) to a working solution - no error and no need to use change detection.

good luck!

Answer (score 7):

Basically, the angular is detecting the change after it has already set the value as `null` for both values. So, you need to explicitly tell angular that it should run change detection. [Check out this demo code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-fxntqm-pndpwc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

I have removed the logic of using `get` because its a bad practice to call a function directly from an HTML. It'll be called multiple times. Try putting console log in your code and see.

I have used `ngAfterViewInit` along with `ChangeDetectorRef` to inform.

```
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  title = 'mat-stepper';

  form1: FormGroup;
  form2: FormGroup;
  @ViewChild('stepOne') stepOneComponent: FirstStepComponent;
  @ViewChild('stepTwo') stepTwoComponent: SecondStepComponent;

  constructor(private cdr :ChangeDetectorRef){}

  ngAfterViewInit(){
    this.form1 = this.stepOneComponent.frmStepOne;
    this.form2 = this.stepTwoComponent.frmStepTwo
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
  }

}
```

This will solve the error

Comment: I think one more thing you can try is QueryList which has a `change` feature which acts as an observable to be subscribed.  Check that out as well

Comment: I say don't mess with change detection unless you have to!! try the solution I offered and you'll see that you don't have to.

Comment: now I dont kow what to accept as the answer because both fix the issue I have

Comment: @vigamage: WHich ever you feel like :D and seems easy. Try the comment part as well which i mentioned

Comment: @vigamage please note that my answer saves you an unnecessary change detection! this issue will repeat a lot in many of your app components, in terms of performance, I leave the calculation for you.

Answer (score 3):

A really easy way to handle this is by declaring the form group in the child, and in the parent template, you have the ability to reference it! The main benefit of this is that it is wonderfully type safe and a lot cleaner than all the other options.

```
<mat-step [stepControl]="step1.step1Form">
  <app-step1 #step1></app-step1>
</mat-step>
```