# Angular 6 MatTable Performance in 1000 rows

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2, angular-cdk

I'm using angular material in my project and I'm using Mat-Table to render 1000 Product/row per table.
When Change pagination (we use backend pagination) of table to 1000 rows the performance become very slow I even can't write in textboxes.

I tried to debug the issue so I put logs on one column template so I can see how's render works.

I see it's Rerender all rows  even if I hover on the table headers.
Is there's any possibilities to control the change detection to be like
ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush

[image]

Comment: Why are you pulling 1000 rows?  That's a lot of data coming across the wire.  And almost no matter which framework you're using, you're going to see a sluggish behavior with that much rendering.

Comment: We was using html tables without angular and it was works perfectly and we want to do operations on bulk

Comment: Nice observation. I am also facing the same issue even for 32 rows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had solved this issue and I improved the performance by wrapping the table in custom (grid) component and Control the `changeDetection` of the component to be `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` and when I want to render update I used `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()`

Comment: Can you expand on this please?

Comment: I have tried doing that, but when I hover on headers, it still renders everything again

Comment: Not relevant for any use cases

Answer (score 99):

Not sure if this will help your situation as there's no code but we've found that the MatTable loads very slowly if a large data set is set *before* you set the datasource paginator.

For example - this takes several seconds to render...

```
dataSource: MatTableDataSource<LocationItem> = new MatTableDataSource();
@ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
@ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;

ngOnInit() {
  this.dataSource.data = [GetLargeDataSet];
}

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
}
```

...but this is fast

```
ngOnInit() {
  // data loaded after view init 
}

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;

  /* now it's okay to set large data source... */
  this.dataSource.data = [GetLargeDataSet];
}
```

Incidentally, we were only finding this issue the second time we access the component as the large dataset from server was being cached and was immediately available the second time component was accessed.  Another option is to add .delay(100) to your observable if you want to leave that code in the ngOnInit function.

Anyway, this may or may not help your situation.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this 1 million times! Too bad I decided to try to search for an answer after I spent 2 days profilling my entire application thinking that I had some  code being called many times and decreasing the table performance because even with 100 items in the datasource it was getting very slow to update.

Comment: I almost decided to go with another datatable library. Thanks mate. This performance issue should be at least specified in the documentation!

Comment: Without assigning data to datasource if I set first paginator I'm getting paginator undefined .. please help !
This is how I've done -
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.reportData);
   this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;

Comment: @Priyanka I get the same thing, did you ever resolve it?

Comment: @Turneye: I'm having an issue with your solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58518445/not-able-to-set-initial-pageindex-in-mat-paginator-when-dealing-with-large-datas

Comment: wow this drastically improved the performance of my Sort. Thank you

Comment: For me helped to set the table data to ngAfterViewChecked

Comment: Thanks to your solution I managed to solve performance issues that was happening even loading bunchs of 300 data. Thank you so much!

Comment: I'm not using a pagination at all, similar to the example Basic use of `<table mat-table>` on the docs, but I'm still getting very slow load times, 10 seconds for 300 items

Comment: I struggled for hours with the slowness of MATTABLE loaded with few thousand lines when I returned from another page, the solution was simple, display the table only when *ngIf true, I set it true at ngAfterViewInit.

Comment: This solution throws change detection errors. I prefer @poul-kruijt solution below

Answer (score 20):

To extend upons @Turneye 's answer. The reason it's happening is because the paginator is being set after all the rows have been rendered, because that's what the `ngAfterViewInit` hook tells you.

So it first renders all rows from data source, then it sees: "hey, I'm getting a paginator, let me just remove all the rows (except the pager count)". This is obviously very slow on large data sets and/or complex table cell templates.

You can solve this by using the `{static: true}` option on your `@ViewChild`. This will make the paginator available inside the `ngOnInit` lifecycle hook, and before any row has been rendered:

To steal his code, you can change it to this, and still have a fast table:

```
readonly dataSource: MatTableDataSource<LocationItem> = new MatTableDataSource();

@ViewChild(MatSort, { static: true }) sort: MatSort;
@ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static: true }) paginator: MatPaginator;

ngOnInit() {
  this.dataSource.data = [ GetLargeDataSet ];
  this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
}
```

Be aware though that this will not work if your `mat-paginator` is inside a structural directive like `*ngIf`

---

Another performance issue could be that you have to declare a `trackBy` function:

> To improve performance, a trackBy function can be provided to the table similar to Angular’s ngFor trackBy. This informs the table how to uniquely identify rows to track how the data changes with each update.

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" [trackBy]="myTrackById">
```

Comment: `{ static: true }` worked for me.  I was getting change detection errors using `AfterViewInit`, but didn't know I could push this up into `OnInit`.  Super helpful!

Comment: This trick speed up the rendering speed of my 3000-row table from 5 secs to 0 sec.

Comment: amazing!!! thanks

Answer (score 10):

### Large DataSet Observable Passed Down From Parent Component

After much struggling, I was able to combine pieces of many different answers from this post, including [@turneye's above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51296374/3443552) and the OP's selected right answer, and also answers on another similar SO post, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45467987/3443552) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45467962/3443552).

I had ~1000 rows that I needed for a parent component on the page, as well as several child components, **including a paginated `MatTable` component**.

The data was loading in <500ms, but then the page would take, on average, 15 seconds to render, as originally I was just passing a `MatTableDataSource` object with the data already assigned.

### The solution:

1. Pass an observable with the data, and then subscribe to it after the view initializes, setting the `MatTableDataSource.data` property **after** setting the `MatPaginator` and `MatSort`.
2. Set `changeDetection` to `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` in the `Component` decorator config.
3. After setting the `MatDataSource.data` property in the observable body, tell angular to detect changes with `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()`

Now the full DOM is rendered in ~1 second total, which is fine given the volume of data that needs to be present at once.

Here's a stripped down example:

```js
@Component({
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
    selector: 'app-dynamic-grid',
    templateUrl: './dynamic-grid.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./dynamic-grid.component.scss'],
  })
  export class DynamicGridComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
    @Input() public dataSource$: Observable<any[]>;
  
    public matDataSource = new MatTableDataSource<any>();
  
    @ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static: true }) paginator: MatPaginator;
    @ViewChild(MatSort, { static: true }) sort: MatSort;
  
    constructor(private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {}
  
    ngOnInit(): void {}
  
    ngAfterViewInit() {
      this.matDataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
      this.matDataSource.sort = this.sort;
  
      this.dataSource$.subscribe(x => {
        this.matDataSource.data = x;

        // The important part:
        this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
      });
 
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this using server side sorting and pagination?

Comment: @ManvirSingh nope, this is assuming you're fetching the whole dataset at once.  The data I've had have never been too large to warrant server-side pagination - just the issue with rendering, which I've since resolved.

Answer (score 4):

I have found the `paginator` and `sort` to sometimes not work.

What has worked for me with over 2000 rows was:

```
 ngAfterViewInit() {
      setTimeout(() => {
          this.getLargeDataSet.subscribe(largeDataSet => {
              this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
              this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
              this.dataSource.data = largeDataSet;
          });
      });
 }
```

Supper fast, from 10+sec to 2sec :0

Comment: Are y using backend sorting and pagination or frontend ?

Comment: Frontend @mostafacs

Answer (score 1):

I was having an issue with Turneye's answer giving me an "expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror", so I took inspiration from jabu.hlong's answer.  It turned 5-10 seconds of load time into less than a second.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;

  setTimeout(() => {
    this.dataSource.data = getData(); // Or whatever your data source is
  });
}
```

A side note (mentioned because it seems to be in the same class of issue as the one I was having): I have found it best practice to set the sort before the paginator, because I have run into issues with the reverse when setting matSortActive.

EDIT: Fixed issues with brackets and semicolons.

Comment: please elaborate on your solution in brief.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by elaborate?  Setting a timeout seemed to work, likely because it delayed the setting of the data source until after the table had been fully initialized.  It's probably a bit hacky, and there might be a better way to do it, but it fixed my problem.

Comment: I didn’t have to do timeout. But pagination move to after view init is the key.

Answer (score 0):

I was still facing the problem despite [@turneye's above] solution. For me the solution was to essentially delay the reassignment of the datasource to the last possible moment by doing the following:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    const ds = new MatTableDataSource<ProcessDelaysTable>()
    ds.sort = this.sort
    ds.paginator = this.paginator
    ds.paginator.pageSizeOptions = [5, 10, 50, 100, this.dataPayload.length]
    ds.data = this.dataPayload
    this.dataSource = ds
}
```

Essentially this issue occurs because you are changing a deep property on this.datasource by changing its data after its been checked. However, if you assign this.datasource to a new DataSource object, you change its memory address resolving all conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked using jabus.hlong's answer, but I moved the code to ngOnInit(). There the setTimeout() is not needed.

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.getLargeDataSet.subscribe(largeDataSet => {
       this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
       this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
       this.dataSource.data = largeDataSet;
   });
 }
```