# async datasource with angular material table / angular 7 / nodejs / mongodb

Tags: angular, angular-material

After importing a big database with more than 13.000 documents, I'm experiencing a big delay when displaying the data in my angular material table. I already tried to load the data asynchronously to the table, but was unable to do it. Can someone guide me?

This is how I'm retrieving the data in my component.

```
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

   loadDocuments() {
    this._documentService.getDocuments().subscribe((data: Document[]) => {
      this.documents = data

      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Document>(this.documents );
      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
      this.dataSource.sort = this.sort
      this.sort.sort(<MatSortable>{
        id: 'name',
        start: 'asc'
      });

    })

  }

// searching function

  applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
     this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
  }
```

I've been checking some examples and what they do is declaring as observable datasource... but i could not adapt it.

//EDITED

In my nodejs i have this code

```
  documentsCtrl.getDocuments = (req, res) => {
    documentsModel.find().then((documents) => {
        res.json(documents)
    }).catch(err => {
        res.json(err)
    })
}
```

This function just find all documents that i want retrieve in my component.

This request takes like 4000ms more or less to be displayed in my client

So til this request is completed... i have other function that show a loading spin in my table... but it takes like 4 or 5 seconds to show the data ( the time that the request needs to be completed ) how can i improve this performance?

Comment: i am not sure about that, i am only showing 10 rows in my table, the problem i think is when i ask the data in my server, it takes 4 seconds to load all the data, i am checking it with Morgan... @JohnPeters

Comment: i edited my question, sorry if i did not explain it well.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem displaying around 10'000 rows in an Angular Material table with a paginator and sorting. Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51296374/4606040) answer to another question.

> The key takeaway is to set your `MatPaginator` **before** you assign
>   your data to the `MatTableDataSource`.

Change your code to the following:

```
this.documents = data;
// Initialize with an empty array so you don't get an error when setting the paginator
this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Document>([]);

// Set paginator & sort
this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;

// Finally assign the data
this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Document>(this.documents);
```

Comment: thanks for you answer, i think i didn't explain it well... when the data is loaded, the table works perfectly... my problems is loading the data... it takes 4 or 5 seconds to be displayed... when i call my API to get the data from my database, it takes long time... a solution would be to ask... for example, if my pageSize is 10 rows... ask to the API the first 10 rows... then if i change the pageSize ask for the next rows... something like that...