# Load 7000 lines using mat table at once

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, angular8

I have this code :

```
@Input() data: Array<Users>;
@ViewChild(MatSort, { static: false }) sort: MatSort;
@ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static: false }) paginator: MatPaginator;
dataSource: MatTableDataSource<Users> = new MatTableDataSource();

ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    this.dataSource.data = this.data;
}
```

The paginator and sort is not working, I have all 7000 lines and is very slow. Can you help me please ?

Comment: try to use `virtual Scroll` in your mat-table instead of pagination. it will render your data much faster.

Comment: @FarhatZaman can you give me an example please ?

Comment: https://diprokon.github.io/ng-table-virtual-scroll/#/overview

Comment: or you can use this proper example https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-vs-table-26nq3g?file=src/app/table/table-demo.ts

Comment: why its not better? can you tell me the reasons.

Comment: i mean to say, i wanna know the issues after integration of virtual-scroll with mat-table.

Comment: @FarhatZaman I take a look now and seems I can't install mat-vs-table for angular 8, I have the error `export 'CDK_TABLE' was not found in '@angular/cdk/table` even after `npm install @angular/cdk --save`

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-cdk-table-virtual-scroll

Answer (score 1):

You have to overwrite the dataSource and keep the right order of steps.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Users>(this.data);
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
}
```

Comment: thank you for you answer, but didn't work, to work I put in `ngOnInit` : 
`ngOnInit() {
        this.dataSource.data = this.data; }`
But is very,very,very slow for 7000 lines. I found a post on stackoverflow : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50283659/angular-6-mattable-performance-in-1000-rows

Comment: no, I think because with a lot of data, there no callback in order to know when `this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Users>(this.data);` is finished

Comment: Actually, this shouldn't be that much of a problem. Strange.

Comment: In order to works faster I saw that first should be called : `set paginator, set sort, set data`. but is not working in my case

Comment: I tested it once with 3000 entries and it worked properly. Sorry for being of no help here.

Comment: what about 7000 lines ? :)

Comment: If you really want to know the result, I can do this test. I just have to prepare an appropriate file. I could give you the answer tonight at around 10 p.m. CEST.

Comment: I checked with 7500 entries. 6,5 MB of JSON. No problems detected. Paginator works as expected.