# NG0100: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked when calling a subscribe

Tags: angular, paypal, dialog

I'm trying to open a paypal dialog whenever I'm clicking a button and it gives me an error.

The error is NG0100 and it is stated in the title.

This is the method called by another method whenever the button in pressed and that I'm trying to debug:

```
private purchasePlafond(plafond: Plafond) {
        this._profileService.purchasePlafond(plafond.id)
            .subscribe({ //ERROR OCCURS ON THIS LINE
                next: (res) => {
                    if (!res.error) {
                        const paymentRequest = res.context;
                        const paymentRef = this._paymentService.open(
                            {
                                payment: paymentRequest,
                                message: 'Richiesta in elaborazione...'
                            });
                        paymentRef.afterClosed().subscribe((result: PaymentResponse) => {
                            if (result.type === 'CONFIRMED') {
                                this.initPaymentSuccessDialogForm(plafond);
                            }
                            this.fetchPlafonds();
                        });
                    } else if (res.error) {
                        this._toastService.error(res.message);
                    }
                },
                error: (error) => {
                    this._toastService.error(error.message);
                }
            });
    }
```

I've tried adding a ChangeDetectorRef and using NGZone but I have no idea why this is happening. From this page https://angular.io/errors/NG0100 I could tell that there is something wrong in how I've implemented the subscribe since the article states:

> This error commonly occurs when you've added template expressions or have begun to implement lifecycle hooks like ngAfterViewInit or ngOnChanges. It is also common when dealing with loading status and asynchronous operations, or when a child component changes its parent bindings.

Comment: is the `_paymentService` an angular service?  also, NG0100 is a view error not a subscption error...  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45467962/4604645) is a deep dive