# Scroll down angular 4 when HTML is hidden

Tags: angular, scroll

I'm realizing a chat and I would like to scroll down this chat when the user click on a accordion-group for the 1st time only.

```
<accordion [closeOthers]="true">
   <accordion-group class="headingPanelCust" *ngFor="let discussion of discussions ; let i = index" [isOpen]="discussion.sender.id == show">
     <div accordion-heading class="headingPanelCust" (click)="openDiscussion(i)" (onOpen)="goDown(i)">
         //things here...
     </div>
  <div class="table-wrapper" style="height: 300px" #scrollMe [scrollTop]="scrollMe.scrollHeight" >
   <table class="table">
          <tbody >
                <tr *ngFor="let message of discussion.discussion">
                        <!-->Users info<!-->
                </tr>
               <div id="bottom"></div>
             </tbody>
           </table>
        </div>
```

I tried multiple but I still can't figure out what can I do.
What I tried :

- [This library](https://github.com/NagRock/ngx-auto-scroll)
- [scrollTop] : Gives me a `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` that I can't fix for some reasons
- QueryList :  Problem is that there is only 1 item, even with the same id

Does anyone have an idea ? I'm stuck on this problem since some time now

Comment: Did you ever resolve?

Answer (score 0):

I found this post that fixed my `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` issue that you mentioned having as well. That was a very annoying bug!

[angular2 scroll to bottom (chat style)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35232731/angular2-scroll-to-bottom-chat-style/35278480#35278480)