# scrollToBottom on ionViewDidEnter - Ionic

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

I am developing an ionic chat and I would like the view to point to the bottom of my page when I load my page. 
I tried this method:

```js
    ionViewDidEnter()
    {
          this.content.scrollToBottom(300);
    }
```

But it doesn't work, indeed, I have the impression that the script is loaded too early.

I found this solution that works:

```js
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.content.scrollToBottom(300);
    }, 1000);
```

But I don't find it clean, do you have a better solution?

Thank you in advance for your answer.

Comment: Call that on success of your api which data you're loading on your view. Another solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35232731/angular2-scroll-to-bottom-chat-style/45367387#45367387