# Angular: unable to scroll down to bottom in element

Tags: javascript, angular

I've been postponing fixing this error that I have been having for a while now. I have the below chatwindow:

[image]

The window where I display the messages is a separate component (chat-window.component.ts). I want to scroll to the bottom with ngOnChanges.

When we receive the conversation with the messages from the parent component, where it is received from the server via an asynchronous request, we want to scroll to the bottom of the window element. We do this by calling the `this.scrollToBottom()` method of the class in the ngOnChanges lifecycle hook.

**This.scrollToBottom does get called, but it doesn't scroll to the bottom of the element. Can someone see why?**

**chat-window.component.ts: in ngOnchanges we do some synchronous stuff before we call this.scrollToBottom()**

```
export class ChatboxWindowComponent implements OnChanges, OnInit, AfterViewChecked {

  @Input('conversation') conversation;
  @ViewChild('window') window;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnChanges() {
    // If the date separators have already been added once, we avoid doing it a second time
    const existingDateObj = this.conversation.messages.findIndex((item, i) => item.dateObj);

    if (existingDateObj === -1) {
      this.conversation.messages.forEach( (item, index, array) => {
        if (index !== 0) {
          const date1 = new Date(array[index - 1].date);
          const date2 = new Date(item.date);

          if (date2.getDate() !== date1.getDate() || date2.getMonth() !== date1.getMonth()) {
            this.conversation.messages.splice(index, 0, {date: date2, dateObj: true});
            console.log(this.conversation.messages.length);
          }
        }
      });
    }

    this.scrollToBottom();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  ngAfterViewChecked() {
  }

  isItMyMsg(msg) {
    return msg.from._id === this.conversation.otherUser.userId;
  }

  scrollToBottom() {
    try {
      console.log('scrollToBottom called');
      this.window.nativeElement.top = this.window.nativeElement.scrollHeight;
    } catch (err) {}
  }
}
```

**chat-window.component.html**

```
<div #window class="window">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let message of conversation.messages">
    <div class="date-container" *ngIf="!message.msg; else windowMsg">
      <p class="date">{{message.date | amDateFormat:'LL'}}</p>
    </div>
    <ng-template #windowMsg>
      <p
        class="window__message"
        [ngClass]="{
    'window__message--left': isItMyMsg(message),
    'window__message--right': !isItMyMsg(message)
    }"
      >
        {{message.msg}}
      </p>
    </ng-template>
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

Comment: I forgot to add the template. Up in a second

Comment: Try using `scrollTop` instead of `top` like so `this.window.nativeElement.scrollTop = this.window.nativeElement.scrollHeight`

Comment: I edited it. It didn't solve the problem. I did 4 console.logs to see what they gave me. I did two (of scrollTop and scrollheight) before I did `this.window.nativeElement.scrollTop = this.window.nativeElement.scrollHeight` and two after. The results before were scrollTop is 0 and scrollHeight is 229.

Comment: The results after `this.window.nativeElement.scrollTop = this.window.nativeElement.scrollHeight` are scrollTop is still 0 and scrollHeight is still 229 obviously

Comment: So for some reason it doesn't change the value of  this.window.nativeElement.scrollTop to the value of scrollheight.

Comment: For a test: does it work if you scroll after a delay: `setTimeout(() => { this.scrollToBottom(); }, 500);`?

Comment: Hope this link would help you out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35232731/angular2-scroll-to-bottom-chat-style/45367387

Comment: Hey Connor, it worked! How come I had to do this though?

Comment: I think Suryan's link might explain it.

Comment: Thanks for all the help guys.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The scroll doesn't work because the list of messages is not rendered yet when you call `scrollToBottom`. In order to scroll once the messages have been displayed, set a [template reference variable](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#template-reference-variables--var-) (e.g. `#messageContainer`) on the message containers:

```
<ng-container #messageContainer *ngFor="let message of conversation.messages">
  ...
</ng-container>
```

In the code, you can then access these elements with `ViewChildren` and scroll the window when the `QueryList.changes` event is triggered:

```
@ViewChildren("messageContainer") messageContainers: QueryList<ElementRef>;

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.scrollToBottom(); // For messsages already present
  this.messageContainers.changes.subscribe((list: QueryList<ElementRef>) => {
    this.scrollToBottom(); // For messages added later
  });
}
```

Comment: Great answer. Thanks a lot Connor

Answer (score 3):

You can add the following code into your HTML element.

```
#window [scrollTop]="window.scrollHeight" *ngIf="messages.length > 0"
```

Full code according to your code sample as follows,

```
<div #window [scrollTop]="window.scrollHeight" *ngIf="messages.length > 0" class="window">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let message of conversation.messages">
    <div class="date-container" *ngIf="!message.msg; else windowMsg">
      <p class="date">{{message.date | amDateFormat:'LL'}}</p>
    </div>
    <ng-template #windowMsg>
      <p
        class="window__message"
        [ngClass]="{
    'window__message--left': isItMyMsg(message),
    'window__message--right': !isItMyMsg(message)
    }"
      >
        {{message.msg}}
      </p>
    </ng-template>
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

This is work for me. (Currently, I'm using Angular 11)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```
<div id="focusBtn"></div>

const element = document.getElementById("focusBtn");
element.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth", block: "end", inline: "nearest" });
```

Comment: Where will I write the last two lines of code? Inside ngOnInit or somewhere else? I just want to know how to ensure that it always triggers when the component is loaded and when new messages are sent and received.

Answer (score 0):

- Create a function that handles the scrolling

  `goToBottom(){ window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight); }`
- Add it in ngAfterViewChecked lifycycle

  `ngAfterViewChecked() { this.goToBottom(); }`