# Scroll div to bottom when Observable is completed

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular6

I have a `div` with messages and I want to make sure when all the chat information has been retrieve to scroll the div down to the bottom to the last message, but it doesn't work it gives me this error:

> Cannot read property 'scrollHeight' of null

**TS CHAT COMPONENT**

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.chat$ = this._cs.joinUsers(source).pipe(tap(() => this.scrollBottom()));
  }

  scrollBottom() {
    const CHAT_BODY = document.getElementById("card-body");
    CHAT_BODY.scrollTop = CHAT_BODY.scrollHeight;
  }
```

**Notes:**
The `card-body` element is being loaded by the `chat$ | async`

I have tried to use `finallize()`, and `ngAfterViewInit()` and no luck. **BUT** if I copy past my code from the `scrollBottom()` in the `console` after I see everything on the page, it works fine. So the problem is that is getting trigger and the Observable it's not done yet. maybe?

**My question is different than other solutions I have seen on SO because they aren't using observable an the element don't exist yet when the observable is being triggered.**

**UPDATE:**

I Tried accesing the element using `ViewChild` and got this error:

> I got this error: property 'nativeElement' of undefined

```
  @ViewChild("cardBody")
  cardBody: ElementRef;
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log("Values on ngAfterViewInit():");
    console.log(this.cardBody.nativeElement );
  }
```

**HTML**

```
 <ng-container *ngIf="(chat$ | async) as chat">
    <ng-container *ngIf="(auth.user$ | async) as user">
      .
      .
      <div class="card-body msg_card_body" id="card-body" #cardBody>
      .
      .
      .
      </div>
  </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Why are you executing your `scrollBottom` on `tap`? Why don't you subscribe to your observable? It could be the case, try to subscribe to it and maybe it will fix your issue

Comment: @ggradnig it is getting trigger. If i put  console.log it prints it fine. the problem is the dom element hasn't been loaded

Comment: I see, use `ngAfterViewInit` instead of `ngOnInit` ;-)

Comment: @ggradnig I tried that. I mentioned that in the question :( thanks tho!

Comment: ah sorry, didn't read that, my fault. have you tried to get hold of the component by using `@ViewChild` ? That should give you a "safe" reference. https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild

Comment: @benshabatnoam didn't work ` this.chat$.subscribe(() => this.scrollBottom());`

Comment: @ggradnig ohh. let me try that!

Comment: @ggradnig tried to do that by accessing the viewchild in the afterOnInit. I got this error: property 'nativeElement' of undefined

Comment: I see, that means that the view child wasn't selected correctly. could you add the template where 'card-body' is set to the question?

Comment: @ggradnig I have updated the question

Comment: Please give more context in the HTML markup, especially if the `cardBody` is inside an `ngFor` or an `ngIf` directive.

Comment: @ConnorsFan I have updated my question. please take a look to the HTML part

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular: unable to scroll down to bottom in element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53123912/angular-unable-to-scroll-down-to-bottom-in-element)

Comment: Try accessing the `cardBody` elements in the `QueryList.changes` event handler, as shown in [this duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53124292/1009922).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angular2 scroll to bottom (chat style)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35232731/angular2-scroll-to-bottom-chat-style)

Comment: @ConnorsFan those solutions didn't work since they problem here is the Observable. Thanks tho! I got it working with a setTimeout :(

Comment: You shouldn't have to use `setTimeout`. With `ViewChildren` and `QueryList.changes`, you get notified when the elements have been added to the DOM.

Comment: I used the setTimeout without the viewChild. And the query changes won't work because the element doesn't exist when the ngafterview init is trigger due to the observable :(

Comment: The elements don't exist in `ngAfterViewInit`, but they exist in the `QueryList.changes` callback. Using `setTimeout` is not the correct way to handle this kind of situation.

Comment: @jcal got it working. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @ConnorsFan thanks so much for your help. I will do more research on QueryList. I got it working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally was able to get the solutions to this:

**Solution 1)**

```
 <div  class="card-body msg_card_body" id="card-body" #cardBody
  [scrollTop]="cardBody.scrollHeight">
 .
 .
 </div>
```

**Solution 2)**

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
     this.scrollBottom();
    }, 500);  
}
scrollBottom() {
  const CHAT_BODY = document.getElementById("card-body");
  CHAT_BODY.scrollTop = CHAT_BODY.scrollHeight;
}
```