# Scroll to the bottom of the page after element was added to the DOM - Angular 6

Tags: angular

I have a form where I am adding objects to An array, then I am giving the user a preview of the created objects.

I am looping the array with a *ngFor and each element added to the bottom of the screen. My goal that after each element was added there will be an auto scroll to the bottom of the page

Currently i am using a setTimeOut function, but i was wondering is there a better way?

```
this.createdAppointments.push(appointmentFormValues);

    setTimeout(() => {
      window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight || document.documentElement.scrollHeight);
    }, 1);
```

Comment: why do you even need the timeout? You could create some kind of "scrollOnAppearance" directive which implemented this logic for you to enforce single responsibility and resuability principles.

Comment: @bryan60 I created a directive but the page don't scroll  to the all bottom.
`import {Directive} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    // tslint:disable-next-line:directive-selector
    selector: '[AutoScrollDown]'
})
export class AutoScrollDownDirective {
    constructor() {
        window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight || document.documentElement.scrollHeight);
    }

}`

Comment: do it in afterViewInit instead of the construtor or add a delay of a few ms

Comment: Great! Thank you @bryan60

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular: unable to scroll down to bottom in element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53123912/angular-unable-to-scroll-down-to-bottom-in-element)

Answer (score 1):

You can call scrollIntoView method on newly added items, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView