# Is there a way to scroll to the bottom of the page in angular when clicking a button?

Tags: jquery, html, css, angular, typescript

I am working on an angular project and I need to figure out a way to automatically scroll to the bottom of the page when the user clicks a button.

I tried doing this with the jQuery function animate() which didn't work for me. I have also tried the below function:

```
scrollToBottom() {
  let myElement = document.getElementById("myPageId");
  myElement.scrollTop = myElement.scrollHeight;
}
```

This function only works when I call it from my html page, while I need to use it in my ts file when the user clicks a button.

Comment: Look at this hopefully it will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35232731/angular2-scroll-to-bottom-chat-style

Answer (score 5):

create a button which executes this normal JavaScript as written by @chestas and also [available here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11715646/scroll-automatically-to-the-bottom-of-the-page)

relevant **TS**:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  goToBottom(){
    window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
  }
}
```

relevant **HTML**:

```
<button type="button" (click)="goToBottom()">go to bottom </button>
```

complete [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mpqhkp)

Comment: wow.. super clean! Not sure why people are going for ElementRef and ViewChild for scrolling to bottom... This is definitely the solution for a functionality that scrolls the page down to the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<div style='...' #scrollMe [scrollTop]="scrollMe.scrollHeight">
  <p>
    #scrollMe [scrollTop]="scrollMe.scrollHeight //add in your div
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: [Please do not post an answer that consists essentially of
code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer). Please [edit] your
answer to include an explanation of how and why the code solves the problem,
when it should be used, what its limitations are, and if possible a link to
relevant documentation.

Answer (score 1):

This code helped me

```
<div id="focusBtn"></div>

const element = document.getElementById("focusBtn");
element.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth", block: "end", inline: "nearest" });
```

Answer (score 0):

look at the answer here [Scroll Automatically to the Bottom of the Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11715646/scroll-automatically-to-the-bottom-of-the-page) 
here is the code, just add it inside your function scrollToBottom

```
window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
```

Comment: You should provide detailed answer not one-liner solution. check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

I needed to scroll to the bottom of the page on load, but it didn't work since I am loading a lot of data from API. What worked for me is putting it inside setTimeout function to render the page first and then to scroll down.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.scrollToButtom();
  }

scrollToButtom() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
    }, 500);
}
```