# How do I dynamically scroll a <textarea> in Angular?

Tags: angular, textarea

I am writing a chat application where new messages are added to the bottom of a `<textarea>`. I want the `textarea` to scroll to the bottom because the chatlog is large.

How do I accomplish this?

I tried the following, and `scrollTop` attribute is not scrolling my `textarea`.

```html
<textarea #chat class="form-control" rows=20 disabled [(ngModel)]="output" [scrollTop]="scroll" name="chatMessages"></textarea>
```

However, `this.scroll=9999` does not change the binding of `scrollTop` to the value `9999`. I console log `this.scroll`, and its value is `9999`, but my `textarea` doesn't go to the bottom!

Please I need help, thanks!

Comment: Look at this Answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35232731/angular-2-scroll-to-bottom-chat-style I Hope it can help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have figured out a much simpler approach, that will automatically scroll to the bottom, even when the `ngModel` is being changed in real time (chat). One just has to map the `scrollTop property` of the textarea with its current `scrollHeight`:

```
<textarea [(ngModel)]="..." #textarea [scrollTop]="textarea.scrollHeight"></textarea>
```