# How to manage scroll to bottom when it does not works?

Tags: javascript, angular

I know that this is an usual problem but I cannot solve it with other responses.
I'm using angular to develop a chat component and, as usual, I what the scroll to go down when the chat windows starts and when the user sends a message. I implemented the code here: [Angular 2 Scroll to bottom (Chat style)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35232731/angular-2-scroll-to-bottom-chat-style) but the scroll bar stays a bit above the end of the body as you can see in the next image:

[image: imagen del chat]

I am printing the variables before and after the code in [Angular 2 Scroll to bottom (Chat style)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35232731/angular-2-scroll-to-bottom-chat-style) to see what can be happened and with this code:

```
scrollToBottom(): void {
console.log("ScrollToBottom")
try {
  console.log("scrollTop "+this.myScrollContainer.nativeElement.scrollTop)
  console.log("scrollHeight "+this.myScrollContainer.nativeElement.scrollHeight)
  this.myScrollContainer.nativeElement.scrollTop = this.myScrollContainer.nativeElement.scrollHeight;
  console.log("DONE")
  console.log("scrollTopnew "+this.myScrollContainer.nativeElement.scrollTop)
  console.log("scrollHeightnew "+this.myScrollContainer.nativeElement.scrollHeight)
} catch (err) { console.log(err) }
```

}

I get:

```
scrollTop 0
scrollHeight 1539
DONE
scrollTopnew 1139
scrollHeightnew 1539
```

Also, I have seen that the `offsetHeight` of the div is 400, that is, the scrollHeight minus scrollTopnew but I don't know how to manage it.

The versions are:

- Angular CLI: 10.1.4
- Node: 14.8.0
- OS: linux x64
- Angular: 10.1.4

¿Any idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The scrollHeight points to the top of the component, you have to add the component height to it

Comment: I have done it, even set it like:
this.myScrollContainer.nativeElement.scrollTop = 1539 
to test it. But scroolTop seems to have a maximum that I can exceed