# How to scroll the browser window to a specific position on first view loading with Angular 11

Tags: html, css, angular, frontend

I am displaying a large image contained in the template of a child component through the template of a parent component. Upon loading the view of my parent component, I would like the window of my browser to scroll to a specified position to display the center of that image.

At the moment, 1) upon loading the parent page for the first time : my window does not scroll, 2) upon refreshing the page : my window does not scroll and 3) upon returning to the home screen of my app and going back to the parent component : my window scrolls as wished.

How can I make the window scroll systematically on first loading of the page ?

Thank you all in advance !

**Code samples**

parent.component.ts

```
import { AfterViewChecked, Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "app-parent",
  templateUrl: "./parent.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./parent.component.css"]
})
export class ParentComponent implements AfterViewChecked {
  ngAfterViewChecked() {
    window.scrollTo(1900, 840);
  }
}
```

parent.component.html

```
<app-child></app-child>
```

child.component.ts

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "app-child",
  templateUrl: "./child.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./child.component.css"]
})
export class ChildComponent {}
```

child.component.html

```
<!-- link points to a non-specific 3840 x 2606 jpg image -->
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/5FpYloV.jpg" />
```

**EDIT**

I decided to use a free dragging directive on my main HTML element instead of scrolling around it. I find the dragging more user-friendly that having to wait for the scrolling to end.

Answer (score 1):

Try scrolling in the child instead.

```
export class ChildComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    window.scrollTo(1900, 840);
  }
}
```

You should also calculate position because the current code will fail on different devices.

You could try something like this:

```
<img #imageRef src="https://i.imgur.com/5FpYloV.jpg" />

export class ChildComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('imageRef') image: ElementRef<HTMLImageElement>;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const rect = this.image.nativeElement.getClientBoundingRect();
    window.scrollTo(rect.x, rect.y);
  }
}
```

You mention that the image isn't loaded when you try to scroll, so you can try something like this too:

```
<img #imageRef src="https://i.imgur.com/5FpYloV.jpg" (load)="scrollTo(imageRef)" /> 

export class ChildComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  scrollTo(image: HTMLImageElement) {
    const rect = image.getClientBoundingRect();
    window.scrollTo(rect.x, rect.y);
  }
}
```

Comment: We can also use Angular's `Viewport Scroller` https://angular.io/api/common/ViewportScroller instead of window.scrollTo

Comment: 1) Scrolling from the child component, 2) calculating the scrolling position and 3) using `ViewportScroller` does not change the behavior of my application : it only scrolls the second time that I access the page. Upon first loading, nothing happens.

BUT, upon debugging, I noticed that my image is not even loaded during the `ngAfterViewChecked`. This explains why the scrolling can not work. I need to find a way around this ; I will try a timeout if I have no other choice.

Thank you anyway for your replies!

Comment: @douarremaxime I've updated my answer with another potential solution.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to scroll to position inside the ngOnInit(), it's well described in answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35278480/8049667

Comment: Shouldn’t this be a comment?

Comment: @Vikas don't know, should it ?)

Comment: At that time the image wouldn't be loaded, so the scrolling would fail.

Comment: you can always wrap the image by div and scroll to div, no? @Chrillewoodz

Comment: You can query `dom` in or after ViewInit hook.

Comment: The image is not even loaded during `ngAfterViewChecked`, I need to find an other solution. Still open to suggestions.