# How to update view with object from sessionStorage?

Tags: angular, string-interpolation

I'm passing a user object into sessionStorage. When the next page is showing the string interpolation is not working. Even though the data is passed and the variable is filled.

```
export class ShoppingComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
user: User;
private products: Product[] = [];
private cart: string[] = [];
private subscription: Subscription;

constructor(private shoppingService: ServiceShopping) { }

ngOnInit() {
// this.cart = this.service.getCart()
console.log("User: ", this.user);
this.subscription = this.shoppingService.getAllProducts().subscribe(
  (products: Product[]) => {
    console.log(products);
    this.products = products
    this.user = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('user'));
  }
 )
 }

  ngOnDestroy() {
  this.subscription.unsubscribe()
 }

 }
```

here is the html:

```
<h4>Hello {{user.name}}</h4>
<hr>
<div class="row">
        <app-shopping-item 
        *ngFor="let product of products"
        [product]="product"></app-shopping-item>
</div>
```

the `{{user.name}}` is not updating with the data

Comment: This sounds like it may be an issue with Angular change detection. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50519200/angular-6-view-is-not-updated-after-changing-a-variable-within-subscribe) may help.

Comment: what do you mean by "When the next page is showing" please add the sample code what you have done to  stackblitz then others can easily answer you