# Subscription is not updating template variable

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am working on a browser speech accessibility tool and wanted to show the user the interim results as they are speaking.

The issue I am facing is when receiving data from the speech service the consumer subscription side is not changing the template variable as expected.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log("OnInit -- subscribing");
    this._subscription = this.speech
      .speechInput()
      .pipe(debounceTime(100), distinctUntilChanged())
      .subscribe((s) => {
        if (this.speech.getLastPhrase() != null)
          this.updateFinalResult(this.speech.getLastPhrase());
        this.updateInterimResult(s);  // <------- This call updates `interimResults` variable
        console.log("Subscribe text " + s);
      });
  }
```

When getting results from the service I can see the `console.log` response but `this.updateInterimResults(s)` does not update the template. The only way to see changes is by clicking the button. I don't know why the button makes the variables update.

```
<div>Interim Results: {{interimResults}}</div>
<div>Final Results: {{finalResults}}</div>

<button
  (click)="toggleMic()"
  [style]="microphone ? 'background-color: white' : 'background-color: red'"
  [textContent]="microphone ? 'Record' :'Listening...'"
></button>
```

[Proof of concept demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/browser-speech-interim-results-5xd80p?file=/src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Check out this reply: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51169586/14192128

Comment: Could you share please the this.updateInterimResults code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ChangeDetectorRef` to force the template to check for changes in the variables.

```
constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) { ... }

this._subscription = this.speech
   .speechInput()
   .pipe(debounceTime(100), distinctUntilChanged())
   .subscribe((s) => {
      if (this.speech.getLastPhrase() != null)
        this.updateFinalResult(this.speech.getLastPhrase());
      this.updateInterimResult(s);
      this.cd.detectChanges();
      console.log("Subscribe text " + s);
   });
```

If it still doesn't work try adding it inside `updateInterimResult` instead.