# Angular 6 changing a variable within subscribe doesn't work

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here but my variable is not getting changed inside `subscribe()`. Below is my code snippet where I'm calling `getAllCompanies()` from `save()`. The expectation is that I would be able to assign the updated `cmps` value(the server returns the correct updated value) to `companyList` but it doesn't happen unfortunately. As a result, the rendered view has wrong data because the `companyList` object is not updated:

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
companyList: CompanyMaster[] = []
// lines of code
// ......
// ......
getAllCompanies() {
    this.loaderService.show();
    this.companyService.getAllCompanies().subscribe(cmps => 
      {
        this.companyList = cmps;
      },
      error => { 
        this.toastr.error(error), 
        this.loaderService.hide() 
      },
      () => this.loaderService.hide()
    );
  }

save(formData: NgForm){
 // lines of code
 // ......
 this.companyService.SaveCompanyDetails(company)
.subscribe(data => {
    // lines of code
    // ......
    this.getAllCompanies()
    // lines of code
    // ..
 });
} 

   // lines of code
   // ......
 }
```

I also tried using `ngZone` like it is suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50519200/angular-6-view-is-not-updated-after-changing-a-variable-within-subscribe) but it doesn't seem to work either:

```
this.companyService.getAllCompanies().subscribe(cmps => 
      {
        this.ngZone.run( () => {
          this.companyList = cmps;
       });
      },
      error => { 
        this.toastr.error(error), 
        this.loaderService.hide() 
      },
      () => this.loaderService.hide()
    );
  }
```

Any help would be highly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Your code seems to be fine, you could check the console for any other exceptions. Unless you are using on push changes, the UI should be updated. see this quick example: https://angular-cimdos.stackblitz.io

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine. Can you please add your **companyService** code here?