# Why is ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges() needed for Angular Stripe Integration?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, stripe-payments

[I'm reading through this tutorial on integrating stripe elements with Angular](https://alligator.io/angular/stripe-elements/) and I'm just curious as to why the `onChange` method calls `detectChanges()` at the end.  The `onChange` method is added as an event listener to the stripe card and will assign an error if `onChange` receives one.

```
onChange({ error }) {
  if (error) {
    this.error = error.message;
  } else {
    this.error = null;
  }
  this.cd.detectChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it related from Angular **Change Detection Strategy**.

Default strategy will check the view every time a event is propagated in component (mouse, click, input, XHR, etc). This strategy is not adapted on complex application because performance can be terrible.

An alternative is to use `OnPush` strategy. This strategy will rerender the view only when `@Input` have changed or when you explicitly ask to detect change with `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges();`

Answer (score 1):

Stripe (and some other 3rd party) run outside of angular's zone, then we need to use `ChangeDetectorRef`. Another option to use is also `NgZone`. Got a bit curious myself on how Stripe works outside of Angular zone, since the reasons can vary. For Stripe specifically, according to **[this](https://blog.mgechev.com/2016/07/05/using-stripe-payment-with-angular-2/)**

> The Angular Zones are monkey patching (almost) all asynchronous APIs! Zones intercept async events and triggering the change detection on special events. Zones take care of XMLHttpRequests, fetch, setTimeout, etc. However, Stripe uses hidden iframe for establishing requests to its API, instead of the APIs that zone.js takes care of.

Some further reading on **[zones](https://blog.angularindepth.com/do-you-still-think-that-ngzone-zone-js-is-required-for-change-detection-in-angular-16f7a575afef)** and **[change detection](https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-change-detection-in-angular-8006c51d206f)** and **[difference between NgZone and ChangeDetectorRef](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42971865/angular2-zone-run-vs-changedetectorref-detectchanges)**.

Comment: Thanks - Great answer - It should be the accepted one - but I'm leaving it as is since Martin could use the points.

Comment: No problem, my curiosity is satisfied so that's fine :P