# Why is Angular's ChangeDetection not triggered when using canvas.toBlob() with an arrow function?

Tags: javascript, angular, scope, arrow-functions, angular2-changedetection

I have a very simple component in Angular 10. When a form is submitted the `Blob` of an `canvas`-element is created and stored.

Therefor the releveant part of the `onSubmit()` function looks like this:

```
onSubmit(): void {
  const canvas: HTMLCanvasElement = getCanvas();

  canvas.toBlob((blob: Blob) => {
    this.service.create(blob).pipe(first()).subscribe((response: boolean) => {
      this.isSuccessful = response;
    });
  }, 'image/png', 1);
}
```

**The problem is, that `isSuccessful` is changed, but these changes are not reflected in the
template.**

So what I did is to manually trigger change detection, using a `ChangeDetectorRef`:

```
onSubmit(): void {
  const canvas: HTMLCanvasElement = getCanvas();

  canvas.toBlob((blob: Blob) => {
    this.service.create(blob).pipe(first()).subscribe((response: boolean) => {
      this.isSuccessful = response;
      this.cdr.detectChanges();
    });
  }, 'image/png', 1);
}
```

Now, this works. *But why is it needed here?* In all other cases, when I used an arrow function like this, no change detector was necessary. The `toBlob()` method seems to be different that way.

PS: The `cdr` is also not needed, when the `service.create()` method is outside the `toBlob()`method.

Comment: what is getCanvas() doing? can you share that?

Comment: @ManuelPanizzo This method creates a new `canvas`-element using `this.document.createElement('canvas')` and does some drawings on it. `this.document` was injected like this `@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: HTMLDocument`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change detection is not triggered because `canvas.toBlob` executes the callback outside of the [Angular Zone](https://angular.io/guide/zone). An alternative to calling `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges` is to make sure that the code is executed inside the Angular zone with [NgZone.run](https://angular.io/api/core/NgZone#run):

```
import { NgZone } from '@angular/core';
...

constructor(private ngZone: NgZone) { }

canvas.toBlob((blob: Blob) => {
  this.ngZone.run(() => {
    // Run the code here
  });
}, 'image/png', 1);
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-toblob-8-nz1qvo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) for a demo.

Comment: Ah I see. That totally makes sense. Didn't have the `Zone` in mind. Thanky you. Is there a benefit of using `ngZone.run()` over `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()` in this case or ist it really only an alternative?

Comment: You can take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42971865/1009922) for a comparison between the two methods. In your case, in addition to the arguments given in Gunter's answer, I would prefer `NgZone.run` because it makes the code clear as to the reason why change detection is not called automatically.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link and a good reason to use one over the other.