# To refresh the component after performing POST operation

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, angular-services

I have component called `customers-list` where I am displaying all my customers from the API:

**customers-list.html**

```
<div *ngFor="let customer of customers">
     <p>{{customer.name}</p>
</div>
```

**customers-list.ts**

```
import { Component Input} from '@angular/core';
import { ICustomer} from 'src/app/models/app.models';
import { CustomersService } from 'src/app/services/customers.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'drt-customers-list',
  templateUrl: './customers-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./customers-list.component.scss'],
})
export class CustomerListComponent {
 public customers:  ICustomer[] ;

 constructor(public customersService: CustomersService,) {}

  public async ngOnInit(): Promise<void> {
    this.customers = await this.customersService.getCustomersList('');
  }

}
```

I have another component called `add-customer`, where I will add new customer like this:

```
public onaddCustomer(): void {
    this.someCustomer = this.addCustomerForm.value;
    this.customersService.addCustomer( this.someCustomer).subscribe(
      () => { // If POST is success
        this.successMessage();
      },
      (error) => { // If POST is failed
        this.failureMessage();
      }
    );

  }
```

Now `POST` operation happens fine, but the `customer-list` is not updated without refreshing the page.

How can I update the `customers-list` component after successful `POST` operation, without refreshing the whole page?

**services file:**

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ICustomer} from 'src/app/models/app.models';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})

export class CustomersService {
 private  baseUrl : string = '....api URL....';

  public async getCustomersList(): Promise<ICustomer[]> {
    const apiUrl: string = `${this.baseUrl}/customers`;

    return this.http.get<ICustomer[]>(apiUrl).toPromise();
  }

public addCustomer(customer: ICustomer): Observable<object> {
  const apiUrl: string = `${this.baseUrl}/customers`;

  return this.http.post(apiUrl, customer);
}


}
```

Comment: You need to call this.customersService.getCustomersList('') after complete post request successfully.

Comment: I tried this approach, it didn't worked.

Comment: can you show how did you try, because you have to update this.customer by featching latest data from this.customerService.getCustomerList...

Comment: Are you using ngOnChanges to catch the customers changes ?

Comment: Where in `customer-list component` or `add-customer component`? @MehdiBenmoha

Comment: in the `customer-list` component. I have had the same issue once: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48264304/angular-5-ngonchanges-fires-only-once-in-child-component

Comment: You have raised custom flags along the lines of "I need help" *sixteen times* and they have been declined *every time*. Flags are for issues that require moderator intervention, *not* for drawing attention to your question. Please stop misusing flags.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main reason it is not refreshing because ngOnIniit executes only at the time of initialization. I am assuming you are not using any state management library ( data store ) so the best solution will be use a Subject in CustomerService.  Here is the code, it may not compile, i just quickly wrote it in notepad for you. Also you need to make sure you add method is really adding customer and getCustomer method really getting the newly added customer. If both are working then my solution will work.

**CustomerListComponent**

```
import { Component Input} from '@angular/core';
import { ICustomer} from 'src/app/models/app.models';
import { CustomersService } from 'src/app/services/customers.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'drt-customers-list',
  templateUrl: './customers-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./customers-list.component.scss'],
})
export class CustomerListComponent {
 public customers:  ICustomer[] ;

 constructor(public customersService: CustomersService,) {}

  public async ngOnInit(): Promise<void> {
    this.initCustomerAddedSubscription();
  }

/**
 * This subscription will execute every single time whenever a customer is added successfully
 *
 */ 
  public initCustomerAddedSubscription() {
    this.customersService.customerAdded.subscribe((data: boolean) => {
        if(data) {
            this.customers = await this.customersService.getCustomersList('');
        }
    });  

  }

}
```

**CustomersService**

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ICustomer} from 'src/app/models/app.models';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})

export class CustomersService {
 private  baseUrl : string = '....api URL....';
 // use this subject in onAddCustomer method
 public   customerAdded: Subject<boolean>;

 // constructor to initialize subject
 constructor() {
    this.customerAdded = new Subject<boolean>();
 }
 public async getCustomersList(): Promise<ICustomer[]> {
    const apiUrl: string = `${this.baseUrl}/customers`;

    return this.http.get<ICustomer[]>(apiUrl).toPromise();
  }

public addCustomer(customer: ICustomer): Observable<object> {
  const apiUrl: string = `${this.baseUrl}/customers`;

  return this.http.post(apiUrl, customer);
}


}
```

**onaddCustomer Method**

```
public onaddCustomer(): void {
    this.someCustomer = this.addCustomerForm.value;
    this.customersService.addCustomer( this.someCustomer).subscribe(
      () => { // If POST is success
        // You can pass in the newly added customer as well if you want for any reason. boolean is fine for now.
        this.customersService.customerAdded.next(true);
        this.successMessage();
      },
      (error) => { // If POST is failed
        this.failureMessage();
      }
    );

  }
```

Comment: I am getting this lint error in `customer-list` component: **'await' expression is only allowed within an async function.**

Comment: put async  in the function as you did in ngOnInit()

Answer (score 0):

The `ngOnInit` only runs once. You have assigned the customers variable in the `ngOnInit`. So, it is updating only on refreshing. You need to assign the value to `this.customers` every time the request is completed.

Answer (score 0):

```
constructor(public customersService: CustomersService, private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {}
    public onaddCustomer(): void {
        this.someCustomer = this.addCustomerForm.value;
        this.customersService.addCustomer( this.someCustomer).subscribe(
          () => { // If POST is success
            this.customers = await this.customersService.getCustomersList('');
            console.log(this.customers) //are you getting updating list here without refreshing.
             this.cd.markForCheck();
          },
          (error) => { // If POST is failed
            this.failureMessage();
          }
        );

      }
```

Comment: did you check this.customers list updated successfully  by console output?

Comment: Let me console the customer-list once

Comment: `customer-list` console shows the list of `customer` only on page reload, It's not showing after `POST` operation.

Comment: check above console.log comment once

Comment: you need to console there and check

Comment: In the log i am able to see the added object(i,e contact) properties, still the list is not refreshing.

Comment: check my updated code above please try ChangeDetectorRef and when you get the updated list call this.cd.detec....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190433/discussion-between-empty-soul-and-mukesh-gupta).