# Variable not updating in template when set inside subscribe method

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

I have an observable variable that gets its value from the store.
I have a subscribe method on it to listen to updates. In it I try to assign a regular variable one of the values of the observable variable. 
I console log it to see if it has been updated and it has but the value is not updated in the template.

I have tried listening to the observable in the template and that works fine. I need however to manipulate the returned answer so I can't do it this way.

I have also tried with

```
this.cdr.detectChanges();
```

and that works but it feels hacky and overkill for something so simple.
Also just in case someone wonders my component does not have

```
ChangeDetectionStrategy=OnPush
```

.

This is how the variable is initialised.

```
this.filters$ = this.store.let(getListsContactsFilters());
```

This is what the subscription looks like.

```
this.filters$.subscribe((filters) => {
   this.selectedAreas = filters.selectedAreas;
});
```

I then do this in the template

```
<div *ngFor="let area of selectedAreas">
  <h1>{{area.title}}</h1>
</div>
```

I also tried printing out selectedAreas in the template:

```
{{selectedAreas | json}}
```

and this stays as an empty array even after the subscribe function is triggered.

Really super simple so god knows why it is not working.

I expect this.selectedAreas to have the value of filters.selectedAreas in the template. Which btw is and array of objects.

Comment: updated my answer

Comment: @thnksfrthmmrs make sure there is not another function firing at same time that is blocking or obscuring the intended result. If there is, you may need to add {emitEvent: false}

Answer (score 1):

I have been through the same problem, the point is that Angular is unable to detect changes outside of its scope (in this case ngRx). I think you can't get it working without that detectChanges statement. It's not overkill, it's how angular works.

Here's a link to my question:

[Angular 5 ngOnChanges fires only once in child component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48264304/angular-5-ngonchanges-fires-only-once-in-child-component)

Comment: How come OP's code works fine if you do the subscribe in the template using the async pipe? It's only when you do a manual subscribe as OP describes where it doesn't get updated...

Answer (score 1):

Please try

```
<div *ngFor="let area of (selectedAreas | async)">
```

It helped me. I used in

```
this.autoUploadSubscription = this.flow.events$.subscribe(event => {}

<tr *ngFor="let attachment of  (flow.transfers$ | async).transfers"></tr>

trackTransfer(transfer: Transfer) {
  return transfer.id;
}
```

https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/angular-question-rxjs-subscribe-vs-async-pipe-in-component-templates-c956c8c0c794

---

```
records$: Observable<any>;

ngOnInit() {
  this.records$ = this.clientService.getAll(1, this.pagesize);
}

<table *ngIf="records$ | async as records">
  <tr *ngFor="let record of records.data">
```