# How to detect change to a property in Angular

Tags: angular

I have a component with a sub component `timeline`.

```html
<app-timeline [(editing)]="editingDate"></app-timeline>
```

In the timeline component I have these properties:

```ts
@Input() editing: boolean; // <--- detect change on this
@Output() editingChange = new EventEmitter();
```

How can I check when a change to the `editing` property occurs from the timeline component? I need to emit the editing value whenever it changes.

Should I use a setter for the editing property then emit from there?

```ts
private _editing
set editing() { ... // emit }
```

Or is there another way?

Comment: Refer : onChanges method, https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges, this can get you which property is changed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect when an @Input() value changes in Angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38571812/how-to-detect-when-an-input-value-changes-in-angular)

Comment: I'm trying to send data from a component up through 2 components would it be better to use a service or should I emit through the 2 components?

Comment: making service is a better option.

Answer (score 27):

The ngOnChanges can be used exactly for this

First make sure your component implements the ngOnChanges like this

```ts
export class TimelineComponent implements OnChanges
```

Then implement the ngOnChanges method like this

```ts
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if (changes.editing) {
        console.log(changes.editing.currentValue);
    }
}
```

Any time any input was changed it will enter the ngOnChanges method. This is also why the if statement was added since if any other input was changed the `editing` property won't exist on the `changes` object.

For primitive values it will trigger on any change. For reference values you need to change the actual reference, just changing a property of the object you have in the input won't work.

Answer (score 9):

**ngOnChanges** looks for every change in the component lifecycle. Using it is kinda overkill.

You don't need two-way binding(again it's up to you and the requirement)

Just use property binding instead...

```
<app-timeline [editing]="editingDate"></app-timeline>
```

Whenever `editing` sets then you have to emit the `Output()`

```
@Output() editingChange = new EventEmitter();

public get editing(): boolean {
   return this._editing;
}

@Input()
public set editing(edit: boolean) {
    if (edit) {
        this._editing = edit;
        this.editingChange.emit("something");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use ngAfterViewChecked callback method and lastEditing flag for testing if editing changed:

```js
import {
  AfterViewChecked,
  Component,
  EventEmitter,
  Input,
  Output,
} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-example',
  templateUrl: './example.component.html'
})
export class ExampleComponent implements AfterViewChecked {
  @Input() editing: boolean = false;
  lastEditing: boolean = false;
  
  @Output() editingChanged = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

  ngAfterViewChecked(): void {
if (this.editing != this.lastEditing) {
      this.lastEditing = this.editing;
      this.editingChange?.emit(this.editing)
    }
  }
}
```

This component could be used like this:

```
<app-timeline [editing]="editingDate" (editingChanged)="eChanged($event)" ></app-timeline>
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Comment: Please, write me what is wrong with my answer?
Why is this the reason for blocking me from asking questions?

Comment: Nothing I’ve done is blocking you from asking questions. I simply gave you advice for how to improve your answer so it’s more helpful to future readers. The Stack Overflow system will automatically block you from asking questions if you post a number of questions that are don’t meet Stack Overflow’s standards and are subsequently deleted.