# Angular 12 or 13 Observers vs Ember.js

Tags: javascript, angular, ember.js

I have been working in Ember.js since last 8 years. Now switched to Angular.js Version 13
In Ember.js if I have to do something when some variables of model change, This was the code

Following code is from Ember.js how can we do the same in Angular.js version 13 or 12

```
import { observer } from '@ember-cli';
import SomeOtherModel from 'app/models/someothermodel';

foo1:null,
foo2:[],
foo3:false,
SomeOtherModel:someOtherModel

fooObeserver: observer('foo1', 'foo2', 'foo3', 'someOtherModel.foo9', 'someOtherModel.foo12', function(){
      //do bla bla
      this.anymethod();
      this.someOtherModel.anymethod();
      .....
});
```

Note: fooObserver is not referenceable but whenever these variables will change this block will be executed.

Comment: that version of ember is this? I've never seen an import from `@ember-cli`?

also, this looks like invalid JS syntax? is code missing?

Comment: yes, that Ember.js and syntax is correct let me just update it
also its JUST SNAPSHOT of the code ;)

import { observer } from '@ember/object';

Comment: @NullVoxPopuli My purpose is to find way of writing observer as we do in ember.js

Comment: Use the `ngOnChanges` life cycle hook. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54267876/12914833