# Angular 12: Trigger multiple child components at once

Tags: angular, angularjs

I have a situation where Parent component is having 5 DIFFERENT CHILD COMPONENTS rendered, and on a button click from parent or a value change of parent, all 5 child components should do something (execute a method)

Please suggest a stand practice in Angular 12 or 13 versions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest a shared service and an RXJS `Subject`.

Here's an example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fvllm7?file=src/app/app.component.ts

**Service**

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class DoSomethingService {
  subject = new Subject<void>();
}
```

**Parent**

```js
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private doSomethingService: DoSomethingService) {}

  makeSomethingHappen() {
    this.doSomethingService.subject.next();
  }
}
```

```html
<button (click)="makeSomethingHappen()">CLICK ME</button>

<app-one></app-one>
<app-two></app-two>
<app-three></app-three>
```

**Children**

```js
export class OneComponent implements OnInit {
  message = 'Component one standing by...';
  sub = new Subscription();

  constructor(private doSomethingService: DoSomethingService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.doSomethingService.subject.subscribe(() =>
      this.doSomething()
    );
  }

  doSomething() {
    this.message = 'Component one did something!';
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.sub.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Comment: This was helpful. If you can answer my another question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/71761190/5523139
Thanks