# Trigger function on @Input() changed

Tags: angular, input, components, parent

I have a parent component with the following code in the parent.component.html:

```html
<app-child [idElement]=(idElement)></app-child>
```

In the child component, I have the input parameter like this:

```js
@Input() idElement : number;
```

And also a function called

```js
getSpecs()
```

I want the `getSpecs()` function to be executed by the child when the input is modified by the parent. Is that possible?

Comment: https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/

Comment: Like this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38571812/4636715 ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For that purpose, you have to use the Angular lifecycle hook `ngOnChanges`.

In your case it would be something like:

```js
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if (changes['idElement']) {
        // Do your logic here
        this.getSpecs()
    }
}
```

The documentation is [here](https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges).

Answer (score 9):

There is another option without `OnChanges`.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-child',
    template: '<div></div>'
})
export class AppChildComponent {
    private _idElement: number;

    get idElement(): number {
        return this._idElement;
    }

    @Input('idElement') set idElement(value: number) {
        if (value) {
            this._idElement = value;
            this.getSpecs();
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try these one

1. Import `OnChanges` from angular core package in your  `child component`

   `import { Component, Input, OnChanges , SimpleChanges} from '@angular/core';`
2. Implement you child class like

   `export class YourComponent  implements OnChanges`
3. Create `OnChanges` method like

   ```
   ngOnChanges(changes:SimpleChanges){
     console.log(changes.your input property name);
    // implement your logic here  
   }
   ```

Whenever you have changes in parent component it will affect in child component