# Angular 6: onChage mat-slide-toggle conditional validation to select only one option from array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, angular-material

I have a list of the `mat-slide-toggle`. At a time only one slider will remain enabled and other slider will remain disabled.

Now while clicking on that enabled slider it's value will be changed and simultaneously other list of slider will be get enabled for selection and once the one slider will be get selected then other will be get disabled.

So, in short from the whole array only one `mat-slide-toggle` should be selected and other will be disabled simultaneously.

For that I have make the code as below.

```
<form [formGroup]="selectionForm">
  <div class="row">
    <div formArrayName="selectOption">
        <div *ngFor="let select of selectionForm['controls'].selectOption['controls']; let i=index">
            <div [formGroupName]="i">
                <div formArrayName="selectionList">
                        <div *ngFor="let obj of select.controls['selectList'].controls; let j = index">
                    <div [formGroupName]="j">
                    <mat-slide-toggle formControlName="isSelected"" (change)="changeSelection($event)" disabled="slidValue || obj.isSelected === false"> Is selected? </mat-slide-toggle>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

In TS code:

```
public slidValue;
changeSelection(event) {
 this.slidValue = false
}
```

[Sample JSON Response](https://jsfiddle.net/byk4d036/)

[StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-a2xvee?devtoolsheight=33&file=src/app/app.component.ts).

Eg: On load of the page:

[image]

Now when change the slide toggle all other options value not getting change from false to true for selection.

[image]

Comment: Condition logic here is not defined as expected: "obj.isSelected === true".
If I understand correctly what you're trying to achive you should define it as following:
"obj.isSelected === true || noneIsSelected"

Comment: There is a button should be always selected.

Comment: You have to explain which value should be selected and which value will be triggered

Comment: That `isSelected` value will be selected and apparently while changing that value from `true` to `false` at that time other options will be enabled for selection.... and once the one option is selected at the same time other will be changed to disabled !!!