# how to count *ngif inside *ngfor

Tags: angular

I want to know how many items are displayed in following piece of code.

component.html:

```
<p *ngIf="counter">{{counter}} items displayed!</p>
<p *ngIf="!counter">Nothing to display!</p>

<ng-container *ngFor="let item of items">
  <li *ngIf="item.count < 100">{{counter}}. {{item.title}}</li>
</ng-container>
```

component.ts:

```
export class ListComponent {
  @Input('items') items: any[];

  constructor() { }

  protected counter: number = 0;
}
```

items (json presentation):

```
[
    {id: 1, count: 100, title: "title #1"},
    {id: 2, count: 20, title: "title #2"},
    {id: 3, count: 0, title: "title #3"},
    {id: 4, count: 200, title: "title #4"},
    {id: 5, count: 100, title: "title #5"},
]
```

Note 1: In above sample data, only `count` property of objects in the array can change at any moment of time, by any other component of the app.

Note 2: Actually, `items` is an array of arrays, but for better representation and better understanding I changed it to array of objects here.

---

I tried to count HTML nodes but this error happens:

```
NG0100: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError
```

I also tried *ngIf="addCounter(item.count < 100)" but addCounter() is triggered on every event on page (scroll events, etc).

I also can not filter `items` in the ts file (there are lots of ngfors and the `items` is constantly updated, so the ts file gets too complicated because of just a simple counter).

Is there a better approach out there?

Answer (score 1):

You should do all data filtering, processing, and preparation in the component class. The template should be used for displaying data only. This is some approach to display the items according to the conditions mentioned in the question:

component.ts

```js
filteredItems = items.filter(item => item.count < 100);
counter = filteredItems.length;
```

template.html

```js
<p *ngIf="counter">{{counter}} items displayed!</p>
<p *ngIf="!counter">Nothing to display!</p>

<ng-container *ngFor="let item of filteredItems; let i = index">
  <li>{{i}}. {{item.title}}</li>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Thank you, but `items` is sent to the component via @Input(). Where should I put the filter line? And also how can I update it when `items` is changed?

Comment: No problem at all you can detect @Input changes using [`ngOnChanges`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44686085/7149235)

Comment: It seems like ngOnChanges() doesn't detect changes of inner items, e.g. `items[index].count`. Probably only detects changes to `items` itself?! (in my app, `count` property of objects in `items` array is updated but total number of objects in `items` array is not changed at all).

Comment: You can use set property on input to make the changes by creating a filter.

Answer (score 0):

As per the comments, you can add a counter in the TS file add a method to increment every time `item.counter < 100`;

**Updated Answer** based on the comment and extra information provided in the question.

You can use `set` property on `input`. Create two variables: `counter`(already there) and `itemList` in the ts file :

```
export class ListComponent {
  protected counter: number = 0;
  public itemList: Array<any>= [];
  @Input('items') set item (value) {
      console.log(value) // now you get items here
      this.itemList = value;
      this.filterBasedOnCount(value);
  }

  constructor() { }
  
  filterBasedOnCount(items) {
     this.counter =  items.filter(item => item.count < 100).length;
  }
  
}
```

> Note 2: Actually, items is an array of arrays, but for better
> representation and better understanding I changed it to array of
> objects here.

You can use flatMap in the filter to get only the list of object just for counting purpose.

Comment: I want to show all items where items.count < 100 (or any other condition), and I want to show how many items are displayed. I'm not looking for pagination, but to count how many times *ngif is true (how many <li> is displayed). Thank you, but a simple *ngfor index is not what i'm looking for.

Comment: Update the answer please check this if it helps.

Comment: I already tried this (as I mentioned in my question before). Now countItem() is triggered on every event, e.g. with page scroll. If there are 10 items to display, it goes up and up with scrolling the page. also NG0100: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError is thrown on every trigger.

Comment: Is It possible for you to add the whole code because it is difficult to give in depth answer with this piece.

Comment: Updated the answer, you can check now.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like this:
Create the interface for the JSON

```js
export interface ListItem {
  id: number;
  count: number;
  title: string;
}
```

And use it in your component.ts:

```js
@Component({selector: 'app-list', changeDetection: ChangeDetection.OnPush})
export class ListComponent {
  @Input() items?: ListItem [] | null; // with ? and | null your component will work with async pipe and strict TypeScript
}
```

Your `ListComponent` html:

```html
<p *ngIf="items?.length">{{items.length}} items displayed!</p>
<p *ngIf="!items?.length">Nothing to display!</p>

<ol> // It's always better to use native html element.
  <li *ngFor="let item of items">{{item.title}}</li>
</ol>
```

Create an [Angular pipe](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#creating-pipes-for-custom-data-transformations) that does all the logic:

```js
@Pipe({name: 'countFilter'})
export class CountFilterPipe implements PipeTransform{
  transform(value: ListItem[] | null | undefined) { // with the above logic mark null | undefined too.
    if(!value) {
      return;
    }
    return value.filter(item => item => item.count < 100);
  }
}
```

Your `AppComponent` or any component html where you use `app-list`:

```html
<app-list [items]="items | countFilter"></app-list>
```