# How can I replace the object bound to an Angular component?

Tags: angular

I have a parent component that creates an object `myObject` with an array property `myArray`. It injects this object into a child component via one-way binding. The child object uses `*ngFor` to display members of the array, and it has further child components that bind to properties of the objects in the array, and so on.

I am attempting replace `myObject` with a new object via `myObject = new MyObject()`, or to empty `myArray` via `myObject.myArray.length = 0;` or  `myObject.myArray = [];`

My expectation is that the child component would then display nothing until I re-populate the array. Instead, in any of the above cases, the child component continues to display the elements of the array as though I hadn't touched`myObject` or `myArray` at all.

I've tried a few methods of forcing a refresh that I found elsewhere on StackOverflow to no avail, so please excuse a bit of clutter in the current code.

**Parent component (.ts)** - This function is called when I press a certain button in the template:

```
create() {
    this.active = false;
    this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
    this.myObject = null;
    this.myObject = new MyObject();
    this.myObject.myArray = null;
    this.myObject.myArray = [];
    this.myObject.myArray.length = 0;
    this.active = true;
    this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
}
```

I've tried to see what happens when I do `console.log(myObject)` immediately after every line of this create() function. In every single case, what I get in the console looks like this:

`MyObject {myArray: Array(0)}`

It **looks** right, but when I expand that object in the console, it shows that `myArray` **actually still has all of the items it had previously**.

**Parent component template (.html)**

```
<my-child *ngIf="active"
    [myObject]="myObject"
></my-child>
```

**Child component (.ts)**

```
@Input() myObject:MyObject = new MyObject();
```

**Child component template (.html)**

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of myObject.myArray">
    <another-child-component
        [item]="item"
        etc.
    ></another-child-component>
</ng-container>
```

I am logging every time the child component's `ngOnInit()` function is called, so I know that the active flag and the changeDetectorRef are forcing it to reinitialize as desired. I also can see the MyObject() constructor getting called enough times to know that the child component is re-instantiating its `myObject` every time it gets reinitialized.

Yet no matter what I do or where I call it from, I can see that the whole system is still displaying the old `myObject` and if I call `console.log(this.myObject)`, no matter where or when, it will always output the old copy.

I don't understand this. Why are my child components hanging onto their old objects even after re-initialization?

Comment: Check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38571812/how-to-detect-when-an-input-value-changes-in-angular

Answer (score 1):

If you want the child to update its `@Input()` value when parent changes it, then you need to use `OnChanges` life cycle hook on the child component.

```
export class ChildComponent implements OnChanges {
  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    console.log(changes);
    // Assign your variables once again here
  }
}
```