# Ionic modal change detection

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular2-changedetection

I have a component using an [Ionic modal](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/modal/ModalController/) to modify the album variable.

```
 addMedias() {
    let self = this;
    let profileModal = self.modalCtrl.create(AlbumAddPage, { album: self.album });
    profileModal.onDidDismiss(data => {
      self.zone.run(() => {
        console.log("ALBUM " + data.album)
        self.album = data.album;
      })
    });
    profileModal.present();
  }
```

I tried to force change detection with `ChangeRefDetector` `markForCheck()` and `detectChanges()`, then I tried to use angular Zones, but when `onDidDismiss()` is called, the view of this component does not update. 
Any thoughts ?

EDIT : here is the modal code :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'page-album-add',
  templateUrl: 'album-add.html'
})
export class AlbumAddPage {
  album: any;

  constructor(
    private navParams: NavParams,
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    private viewCtrl: ViewController,

  ) {
        this.album = navParams.data.album;

  }   

  addMedias(asset){

        this.album.assets.push(asset);
        this.viewCtrl.dismiss({album:this.album});

    }
```

}

Comment: can you share the Modal page code?

Comment: sure, see the edit coming ;)

Comment: the console is logging the data?

Comment: yes, the model is successfully changed in the base component, but ngOnChanges is not triggered

Comment: how are you showing in the view? :)

Comment: with         <my-custom-tag [assets]="album.assets"></my-custom-tag>  :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129614/discussion-between-suraj-rao-and-alexandre-rozier).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i found the trick !

When the `album` value change in the parent, angular does not detect it as "changed" : since I work in the modals with the same album instance, the parent sees no changes with the `album` passed back by the modal.

I had to create a new instance of album and pass it to my modal to make it work (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34796901/angular2-change-detection-ngonchanges-not-firing-for-nested-object) the link that put me in the right direction) :

```
        let self = this;
        let album = this.album; // Copies the album
        this.album = []; // Changes the album 
        let editionModal = self.modalCtrl.create(AlbumEditionPage, {
            album: album
        });
        editionModal.onDidDismiss(data => {
            setTimeout(function () {
                console.log("new album data from edition : ")
                self.album = data.album
                console.log(data.album);
                console.log(self.album);
            }, 0)

        });
```