# Angular 4 - bug detected with PrimNG Datatable

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-datatable

I have detected a bug in Angular 4 or PrimNG Datatables module.

I have a simple view:

```
<span *ngFor="let node of nodes">{{node.label}}</span> //works with case 1,2,3 and 4

<p-dataTable [value]="nodes"> //works with case 1, 2, and 3 (but not with 4!)
     <p-column field="label" header="Label"></p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```

and code in component:

```
private nodes:any[] = []

ngOnChanges() {
   //case 1 -> ok
   //this.nodes.push({label: 'foo'})

   //case 2 -> ok
   //this.nodes = [{label: 'foo'}]

   this.someService.getAll().subscribe(                     
        records => {  
             //case 3 ->ok
             //this.nodes = [{label: 'foo'}]

             //case 4 -> BUG
             //this.nodes.push({label: 'foo'}) //datatable is not updated
        }
   )
}
```

When I run this code with uncommented case 1, 2 or 3 everything is OK but when I am trying to run case 4 (same as case 1 but after service resolve) - prim ng datatables seem not to see changes. In Angular 2 I did not have such issue. Could you explain me what is going on here? :)

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You should have the same behaviour in angular2 and angular4.
In fact it's not a bug, it's the expected behaviour. It as to do with how angular detect change. To detect change angular just do a `===`.

In your case 1 it works because the changeDetection is triggered by the ngOnChange itself.

But in your case 4 you just add a value to your array without changing the reference of the array `nodes`.

For the other cases you change the reference to `nodes` so angular is able to detect changes.

I advise you to look a this answer it has a lot more details: [Angular2 change detection: ngOnChanges not firing for nested object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34796901/angular2-change-detection-ngonchanges-not-firing-for-nested-object)

Comment: So, why *ngFor detects changes properly but primeng not?

Comment: ho ! I didn't see the comment in the html ... my bad. I tried it and for me it's not working with ngFor... You launched your case 1 by 1 right ?

Comment: how it is possible. Look at any tutorial in internet, when you push something to array it is imiedietelly seen in view when you use *ngFor. Here is the same.