# Ionic2 refresh page

Tags: angular, ionic2

Anybody know how to refresh the page in the ionic application. My app displays a page after sometime getting updated data from webservice and I want to displays the updated data in that page. So I have to refresh the page to displays updated info.

I tried with location.reload, but no luck also don't want to use setroot. Any other way to accomplish this?

Also don't want to use content.ionviewDidLoad() and all.

Thanks 
Ak

Comment: have you tried using observables?

Comment: you do not need to refresh the page to reflect the changes Can you share code?

Comment: Using observables, we updated the object. But how we display the updated data in the page

Comment: you don't need to do anything to update the data in view as long as you have binding to the object which will get the data from service.

Comment: @Vikas: I can't show the entire code. Also i already mentioned that what are the things I tried to get this work. By the way I didn't ask this question without trying anything from my side, also I knew about idownvotedbecau.se/nocode

Comment: I did not ask for entire code Provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Vikas: Simple, getting data from webservice and store it in **Array of Objects**. When the page is getting open, from ionViewDidEnter() fetch the data from Array and display it in ion-list. Once the page displayed after some time, the timer triggers and again webservice fetch the data and update the **ObjectArray**. But we need to update the list once **Array of object" getting updated. Hope you got the scenario and I can give this much info only from myside.

Comment: Fine Have a Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45499982/5695162)

Comment: @Vikas: Thanks bro, it is working now and the problem is UI not getting updated on first refresh. It will get updated on second refresh only

Answer (score 0):

The best way to refresh the page component

```
this.navCtrl.setRoot(this.navCtrl.getActive().component);
```

Comment: it will goes to previous page, if we use this. It won't work

Comment: you can block backbutton action  by using a function in that page

Answer (score -1):

This works in Ionic too and does the trick:

```
   location.reload();
```

Although as mentioned in comments this is not what you would like to do to display asynchronously loaded data in your page template. Have a look at [observables](https://angular.io/guide/observables), [async pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) for a start.

Comment: This is a bad solution. He might need to keep state data. Doing this you reload the whole app.

Comment: The question said nothing about preserving the state data, actually it may suggest he currently does not care about it too much. I also pointed him towards more consistent ways of refreshing data on a webpage. Bests.