# Angular Fullcalendar does not refresh events

Tags: angular, typescript, fullcalendar, observable

I'm trying to use [fullcalendar with angular](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/angular).

Even though valid events are added to my `events` field, they don't show up in the UI. Hard coded events are shown. As I'm quite new to angular, so the error might not be related to fullcalendar.

```
export class CalendarComponent {
  constructor() {}

  events: EventInput[] = [];

  calendarOptions: CalendarOptions = {   
    events: this.events,
    initialView: 'timeGridWeek',
    initialDate: Date.now(),
    locale: 'de',
    nowIndicator: true,
    themeSystem: 'bootstrap',
  };
  
  async onAddEvent() {
    const modalRef = this.modalService.open(NewEventComponent);
    const newShift: Shift = await modalRef.result;
    if (!newShift) return;
    this.events.push(newShift);
  }
}
```

This is the according .html

```
<full-calendar #calendar [options]="calendarOptions"></full-calendar>
```

I figured out that resetting `events` and `calendarOptions.events` does work, is it possible that angular does not recognise the change? What is the correct way? (see below)

```
 this.events = [newShift];
 this.calendarOptions.events = this.events;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone stumbles upon this:

It had nothing to do with fullcalendar. Instead Angular failed to recognise to detect the change. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45499982/change-detection-not-registering-data-changes) answer, resetting the `events` and `calenderOptions.events` solved it.