# ngDoCheck not firing for an object with array of items

Tags: angular, typescript, ngonchanges

I am listening to changes on an object property with help of ngDoCheck The implementation is like below

```
differ: any;
pageSettings:SelectionSettings;
```

where SelectionSettings is

```
export interface SelectionSettings {
  boolPpt: boolean;
  maxRows: number;
  startIndex:number;
  valuesToSelect: Colum[];  
}
```

The property valuesToSelect is an array of items and is dynamic in nature. [ Items can be added to removed from the list as well as items can be updated ]

ngDoCheck  initialization is like below

```
  constructor(  private differs: KeyValueDiffers) {
    this.differ = differs.find({}).create();  
    this.initializeSettings();
  }


  ngDoCheck() {
    var changes = this.differ.diff(this.pageSettings);
    if (changes) {
      console.log('changes detected');
      changes.forEachChangedItem(r => console.log('changed ', r.currentValue));
      changes.forEachAddedItem(r => console.log('added ' + r.currentValue));
      changes.forEachRemovedItem(r => console.log('removed ' + r.currentValue));
    } else {
      console.log('nothing changed');
    }
  }
  


initializeSettings() {

this.pageSettings = {
  boolPpt: false,
  maxRows: 100,
  startIndex: -1,      
  valuesToSelect: [
    {
      name: "sadsa",
      index: -1,
      type: "string",
      bgcolor:"#0000CD"
    },
    {
     name: "xxzc",
      index: -1,
      type: "string",
      bgcolor:"#1000CD"
    }        
  ]
}
```

}

The updation of pageSettings occured at different places inside component, like on click event of a table cell or checkbox change event etc

This is firing for all changes of properties except array  valuesToSelect . Whenever I am adding new items or remove items of the property SelectionSettings.valuesToSelect  , the changes are getting detected.But if we make an updation of already existing item inside  SelectionSettings.valuesToSelect  , ngDoCheck is not detecting any changes.

How can i detect or listen to changes of all properties of SelectionSettings along with child array properties

Comment: I'm assuming you're passing values from the parent component. I'd save valuesToSelect into private variable in child component and would use @Input Setter method. Inside setter overwrite private variable using slice() or '...' operator to make sure change detection is trigerred. Angular change detection will be triggered only if reference to object is changed. If not, then everytime you change object use this.valuesToSelect=valuesToSelect.slice() to trigger change detection. Let me know if it works for you or edit your answer explaining the problem in more detail

Comment: No variable pageSettings is initialized inside constructor of component The question is edited with a part of initialization

Comment: Could you explain how do you change it and try out if reassigning the whole object triggers change detection this.pageSettings.valuesToSelect= newValues?

Comment: This updations occured at various places. Like on click on some table cells / some checkboxes etc

Comment: In those places could you try to reassign whole array like mentioned in above comment?

Comment: i am trying to update just the needed property and leave all other properties as before on all the events. The problem is occuring only for property of array of items

Comment: That's where your problem is. You have to trigger change detection manually or replace the whole object, otherwise change detection cycle won't be triggered. See https://www.mokkapps.de/blog/the-last-guide-for-angular-change-detection-you-will-ever-need#input-reference-changes

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change detection not registering data changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45499982/change-detection-not-registering-data-changes)