# RxJS + Angular: @Input setter doesn't get the updated value from an async source

Tags: angular, ionic2, rxjs

**update**

This issue is linked to my @Input monitoring a nested/array instead of a primitive. It only fires the setter when the references is changed.

- Quick&dirty fix:

Create a new nested/array whenever sending it down the pipe:

```
this._myBehaviorSubject$.next(.this._myBehaviorSubject.getValue().map( entry => entry))
```

- Better approach: [SO discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34796901/angular2-change-detection-ngonchanges-not-firing-for-nested-object)

**original question**
This Ionic 3 / Angular app has a page displaying data from an RxJS observable:

```
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-item>
    Entry count: {{ (journalService.timelineEntries$ | async)?.length }}
  </ion-item>
  <journal-evo-graph [values]="(journalService.timelineEntries$ | async)"></journal-evo-graph>
</ion-content>
```

The `Entry count` printout is just a means of testing that the timelineEntries$ stream is properly feeding the right amount of entries.

The `journal-evo-graph` is a plain NV-D3 graph to render these values. However, the values need to be transformed to be compatible with the graph.

The problem is when the timelineEntries$ values should be obtained.

My `journal-evo-graph` component has an @Input property as follows:

```
export class JournalEvoGraphComponent {

  private _entries: TimelineEntry[];

  @Input('values')
  get values() { return this._entries; }
  set values(entries: TimelineEntry[]) {

    console.log('inbound values ' + entries && entries.length); // stays at 0 even though it fires multiple times

    if(entries && entries.length > 0) {
      this.processTimelineEntries(entries)
    }

    else console.log('no values received.');
  }

  graphOptions:any;

  data: any[];

  constructor() {
    this.initGraphOptions();
    this.initTestData();
  }
```

I can't identify why this component keeps receiving an empty array while the `Entry count:` printout just displays the right amount.

Any leads welcome :-)

Comment: Could you please reproduce your problem at https://stackblitz.com?

Comment: @Jem when trying to debug @Input() issues I usually setup the ngOnChanges lifecycle hook to see what values are being passed into the @Input(). This may help you narrow down where the issue is