# Array - Changes do not propagate to child component

Tags: angular, typescript

The parent:

```
<div id="join-container">
  <join-chain 
    id="my-join-chain" 
    [selectedColumn]="selectedColumn"
    (updatedStatements)=onUpdatedStatements($event)>
  </join-chain>
  <tile-canvas 
    id="my-tile-canvas" 
    [mystatements]="theStatements"
    (selectedColumn)="onSelectedColumn($event)">
  </tile-canvas>
</div>
```

The parent's `ts` code:

```
  onUpdatedStatements(statements: Relational.JoinStatement[]) {
    this.theStatements = statements;
    console.log(">> fired from step-joining")
    console.log(this.theStatements)
  }
```

the child:

```
...
  mappings: Mapping[] = []
  @Input() set mystatements(someStatements: Relational.JoinStatement[] | undefined) {
    console.log(">> tile canvas interceptor")
    console.log(someStatements)
    if (someStatements !== undefined) {
      let idsFromStatements = someStatements
        .map(statement => [statement.leftTile, statement.rightTile])
        .filter(mapping => (mapping[0] !== undefined) && (mapping[1] !== undefined)) as ([Relational.tileId, Relational.tileId])[]
      this.mappings = idsFromStatements.map(ids => new Mapping(ids))
    }
  }
```

I see the message `fired from step-joining` appearing several times as I play with the app.
On the other hand, `>> tile canvas interceptor` happens only one time, after the first `fired from step-joining`.

I read through several posts and have a similar pattern that works, that is the "interceptor" is triggered every time.

Comment: Please consider creating a StackBlitz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In

```
onUpdatedStatements(statements: Relational.JoinStatement[]) {
this.theStatements = statements;
console.log(">> fired from step-joining")
console.log(this.theStatements)
}
```

If statements has the same reference and value as this.theStatements onChange will not be fired in child Component

Comment: From the `console.log` I see `theStatements` changing. Wondering if the fact that we have an array messes up things though.

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34796901/angular2-change-detection-ngonchanges-not-firing-for-nested-object

Comment: Yes, I understand the issue now. How would you deal with the array of objects in order to trigger the change? Thanks!

Comment: @NoIdeaHowToFixThis - You can try `this.theStatements = statements.slice(0);`. That should create a duplicate of the source array.