# adding new optional property in to an existing object does not bind this new property to @input property of the component

Tags: angular, typescript

I am at first creating an instance of a object

```
    export interface IContent {
      type: string;
      name: string;
      color?: string;
      text?: Array<string>;
      xStream?: IValueStream;
      svgType?: string;
      placement?: boolean;
    }

    export interface ITablist {
      id: string;
      text: string;
      content: Array<IContent>;
    }

class something {
tabList: Array<ITablist> = [
        {
      id: 'large_marker',
      text: 'Markers',
      content: [
        { type: 'large_marker', name: 'R', text: ['X:', 'Y:'], svgType: 'r' },
        { type: 'large_marker', name: '1', text: ['X:', 'Y:'], svgType: '1' },
        { type: 'large_marker', name: '2', text: ['X:', 'Y:'], svgType: '2' }
      ]
    }
}
```

Now after some click event I want to add a property `xStream`to existing `tablist`

```
fillMarkerXData(xData: Array<IValueStream>, xDataDiff: Array<IValueStream>): void {
    if (xData) {
      this.tabList[0].content[0].xStream = xData[0];
      this.tabList[0].content[1].xStream =
        this.placement1 ? xDataDiff[1] : xData[1];
      this.tabList[0].content[2].xStream =
        this.placement2 ? xDataDiff[2] : xData[2];
    }
  }
```

but this does not bind it to @input property to child component

```
.html

  <div *ngFor="let length of tabList[0].content; let i = index;">
        <marker [valueStream]="tabList[0].content[i].xStream"></marker>
    </div>
```

Here xstream is not upating in child component after the click event. do someone know how I can achieve this
Thanx in advance

Comment: Can you try using `changeDetectorRef.detectChanges()` after modifying your data?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2 change detection: ngOnChanges not firing for nested object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34796901/angular2-change-detection-ngonchanges-not-firing-for-nested-object)

Answer (score 0):

This should fix it:

In your HTML you are iterating over `tabList[0]` with `*ngFor` but in the click event handler you are changing values in `tabList[1]`

My initial answer:

You might try using lodash cloneDeep:

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#cloneDeep

I think it may not be detecting changes where the object reference has not changed. lodash cloneDeep will ensure that it creates a clone of the object thereby changing the object reference and thus forcing change detection to kick in:

```
fillMarkerXData(xData: Array<IValueStream>, xDataDiff: Array<IValueStream>): void {
  if (xData) {
    this.tabList[1].content[0].xStream = cloneDeep(xData[0]);
    this.tabList[1].content[1].xStream =
      cloneDeep(this.placement1 ? xDataDiff[1] : xData[1]);
    this.tabList[1].content[2].xStream =
      cloneDeep(this.placement2 ? xDataDiff[2] : xData[2]);
  }
}
```