# angular 6 change detection - ngOnChanges not firing for a deep nested object

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6

I am having an object as below

```
result =   [{
        "name": "jmd",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "ppp1",
            "children": [
              {
                "name": "feeder",
                "children": [
                  {
                    "name": "rmu1",
                    "children": [
                      {
                        "name": "IT1",
                        "children": [
                          {
                            "aname": "Asset123",
                            "value" : "233"   
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }]
```

I need to detect the change every time the value changes using `ngOnchanges` event of `Angular 6`.

it seems the angular `ngOnchanges` doesn't detect the deeply nested object.I have tried different things like

```
this.chartData = Object.assign({}, result);
this.chartData = {...result};
```

Nothing is working, any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: why do you have `***` in the last value?.

Comment: i wanted to make it bolder :) .

Comment: Did you try https://stackoverflow.com/a/34799257/3918612 ?

Comment: as mentioned in that post second answer  tried this this.chartData = Object.assign({}, result.data); ,but not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.chartData = Object.assign({}, result);
this.chartData = {...result};
```

this doesn't clone the whole object, it only changes the top-root object, so for example
if you have an object like this

```
var car = {
 model :"bmw",
 wheel:{
  type:"rounded",
  color:"black"
 }
}
```

and you use assign

```
let anotherCar = {...car} //or Object.assign it's almost same)
```

the car object will be new, but the wheel object will be the same, and car and anotherCar will reference to the same object, sou you have to make deep clone, the easiest way right now is using JSON methods

```
var newCar = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(car)); // it will create whole new object
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick note about `Object.assign()` and `{...obj}` object copying: 
both of them make a **shallow** copy of an object meaning that only **own top-level properties** will be copied.

An example:

```
const obj = {a: 5};
const withNested = {b: 4, nested: obj};

const copy = {...withNested};

copy.nested === withNested.nested // outputs 'true' meaning the objects are the same and have not been copied
```

The code above shows that **nested** objects **will not be cloned**.
To make your code work correctly make a deep clone manually: `{...a, b: {...source.b}}` or use `lodash`'s [`_.cloneDeep(source)`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#cloneDeep)

Comment: Alternatively if you don't want to use lodash you can do: `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))` to deep clone an object. Obviously this will not handle circular references.

Comment: Although `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))` will do the work for simple objects, it's not a very good approach:
- it's not idempotent meaning that each subsequent call may return a different output (key order in object is not yet guaranteed); 
- deep clone is way more faster; 
- parse/stringify combo will omit functions; 
- NaN/Inifnity/undefined values will also be omitted;