# The Input() data passed in child component remains same after changing in the child

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

So i am passing an object having length of data and the data itself which is an array of objects

Now what is happening is that when I change the data in the child component and reload the page the data is still showing the edited property

To clarify more see the following screenshots:

1. **When we navigate to the route for the first time there would be no modified data**:
   [image]
2. **When I edit the data**::
   [image]
   As you can see on the right side finalAmount property is added and its value is initialised
3. **Now when renavigate to the same component finalAmount is set to 5**
   [image]

The property itself should not be present in the data as I am getting it from the parent

These are the relevant files:

1. **stepper.component.html (Parent Component)**

```
<mat-step [stepControl]="thirdFormGroup" >
        <ng-template matStepLabel>Prepare Invoice</ng-template>
        <ng-template matStepContent>
            <div class="container-fluid">
            
                <app-create-invoice [selectedCustomersInfo]="selectedCustomerData"
                    [selectedProductsData]="{lengthOfData:cartItems.length , selectedProducts:cartItems}"></app-create-invoice>
            
            </div>
        </ng-template>
    </mat-step>
```

2. **stepper.component.ts:**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-stepper',
  templateUrl: './stepper.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./stepper.component.scss'],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: STEPPER_GLOBAL_OPTIONS,
      useValue: { showError: true }
    }
  ]

})
export class StepperComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  getProductsSubscription = new Subscription
  cartItems: ProductDataModel[] = []
  selectedCustomerData: any
  products = this._formBuilder.group({
    firstCtrl: ['', Validators.required],
  });

  thirdFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
    thirdCtrl: ['', Validators.required],
  });
  stepperOrientation: Observable<StepperOrientation>;

  constructor(private _formBuilder: FormBuilder, breakpointObserver: BreakpointObserver, private cartService: CartService) {
    this.stepperOrientation = breakpointObserver
      .observe('(min-width: 800px)')
      .pipe(map(({ matches }) => (matches ? 'horizontal' : 'vertical')));
  }
  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    console.log("Stepper destroyed");
    this.getProductsSubscription.unsubscribe()
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getProductsSubscription = this.cartService.getProducts().subscribe((items) => {
      this.cartItems = [...items]
      console.log("Cart items::", this.cartItems)
    })
  }

  setCustomerData(customerData: any) {
    this.selectedCustomerData = customerData
  }

}
```

3. **create-invoice.component.html (Child Component):**

```
 <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col">#</th>
                            <th scope="col">Product Category</th>
                            <th scope="col">Sub Category</th>
                            <th scope="col">Master Category</th>
                            <th scope="col">Product Weight</th>
                            <th scope="col">Price</th>
                            <th scope="col">Labour</th>
                            <th scope="col">SGST (In %)</th>
                            <th scope="col">CGST (In %)</th>
                            <th scope="col">Discount</th>
                            <th scope="col">Final Amount</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody>
                        <tr *ngFor="let item of _selectedProductsData;index as i">
                            <th scope="row">{{i+1}}</th>
                            <td>{{item.productCategory}}</td>
                            <td>{{item.subCategory}}</td>
                            <td>{{item.masterCategory}}</td>
                            <td>{{item.productWeight}} gms</td>
                            <td>
                                <input class="form-control priceInput" type="number" id="{{item.productGuid}}-price"
                                    min="0" (input)="item.price = getValue($event,item.id,'price')" #price
                                    placeholder="Enter Price">
                            </td>

                            <td>
                                <input class="form-control labourInput" type="number" id="{{item.productGuid}}-labour"
                                    min="0" (input)="item.labour = getValue($event,item.id,'labour')" #labor
                                    placeholder="Enter Labour">
                            </td>

                            <td>
                                <input class="form-control sgstInput" type="number" id="{{item.productGuid}}-SGST"
                                    min="0" (input)="item.SGST = getValue($event,item.id,'sgst')" #sgst
                                    placeholder="Enter SGST">
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input class="form-control cgstInput" type="number" id="{{item.productGuid}}-CGST"
                                    min="0" (input)="item.CGST = getValue($event,item.id,'cgst')" #cgst
                                    placeholder="Enter CGST">
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input class="form-control discountInput" type="number" min="0"
                                    (input)="item.discount = getValue($event,item.id,'discount')" #discount
                                    id="{{item.productGuid}}-discount" placeholder="Enter Discount">
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                {{ item.finalAmount ?? 0 }}
                                <input class="form-control" type="hidden" [value]="item.finalAmount ?? 0">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>

                </table>
            </div>
```

4. **create-invoice.component.ts:**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-create-invoice',
  templateUrl: './create-invoice.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./create-invoice.component.scss']
})
export class CreateInvoiceComponent implements OnInit,OnDestroy {
  
  _selectedCustomersInfo:any
  _selectedProductsData:InvoiceProductDataModel[] = []
  totalWeight = 0
  totalDiscount = 0
  totalGST = 0
  totalAmountWithGST = 0
  currentDate:Date = new Date()

  @Input() set selectedProductsData(productsData: {lengthOfData:number,selectedProducts:ProductDataModel[]}) {
    this.totalWeight = 0
    this.totalDiscount = 0
    this.totalAmountWithGST = 0
    this.totalGST = 0
    var temp = Object.assign({},productsData)
    this._selectedProductsData = []
    this._selectedProductsData = [...temp.selectedProducts]
    // this._selectedProductsData = [...productsData.selectedProducts]
    this._selectedProductsData.forEach((product) => {
      this.totalWeight += product.productWeight
    })
    console.log(this._selectedProductsData)
  }

  @Input() set selectedCustomersInfo(customerInfo: any) {
    this._selectedCustomersInfo = customerInfo
  }
  constructor() { }
  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    console.log("Create Invoice Destroyed!!")
    this._selectedProductsData = []
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  getValue(event: Event, productId:number, valueOf:string): number {
    let product = this._selectedProductsData.find(item => item.id === productId)
    if (product) {
      switch (valueOf) {
        case 'labour':
          product.labour = Number((event.target as HTMLInputElement).value)
          this.setFinalAmountOfEachProduct(product)
          this.setTotalAmountWithGST()
          break

        case 'price':
          product.price = Number((event.target as HTMLInputElement).value)
          this.setFinalAmountOfEachProduct(product)
          this.setTotalAmountWithGST()
          break

        case 'sgst':
          product.SGST = Number((event.target as HTMLInputElement).value)
          this.setFinalAmountOfEachProduct(product)
          this.setTotalAmountWithGST()
          this.setTotalGST()
          break

        case 'cgst':
          product.CGST = Number((event.target as HTMLInputElement).value)
          this.setFinalAmountOfEachProduct(product)
          this.setTotalAmountWithGST()
          this.setTotalGST()
          break

        case 'discount':
          product.discount = Number((event.target as HTMLInputElement).value)
          this.setFinalAmountOfEachProduct(product)
          this.setTotalDiscount()
          this.setTotalAmountWithGST()
          break

      }
    }
    console.log(this._selectedProductsData.find(i => i.id == productId))
    return Number((event.target as HTMLInputElement).value);
  }

  setFinalAmountOfEachProduct(product:InvoiceProductDataModel) {

      product.finalAmount = 0
      let partialSum = (product.labour ?? 0) + (product.price ?? 0) - (product.discount ?? 0)
      let cgst = product.CGST ? partialSum * ((product.CGST ?? 100) / 100) : 0
      let sgst = product.SGST ? partialSum * ((product.SGST ?? 100) / 100) : 0

      product.totalGST = cgst  + sgst 
      product.finalAmount = partialSum + cgst + sgst
  }

  setTotalDiscount() {
    this.totalDiscount = 0
    this._selectedProductsData.forEach((item)=> {
      this.totalDiscount += item.discount ?? 0
    })
  }

  setTotalAmountWithGST() {
    this.totalAmountWithGST = 0
    this._selectedProductsData.forEach((item)=> {
      this.totalAmountWithGST += item.finalAmount ?? 0
    })
  }

  setTotalGST() {
    this.totalGST = 0
    this._selectedProductsData.forEach((item)=> {
      this.totalGST += item.totalGST ?? 0
    })
  }

}
```

And its not limited to `finalAmount` property it happens with other properties too like discount,sgst etc..

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

From what I've understood you've got a problem with some `data` that have been changed in parent but it's not updated in child component, that have received it thru `@input()`. If I am right, you should read about Angular lifecycle hooks: [HERE](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks). Basically what you need to do, is to implement change detection hooks

```
@Input() someInputData: any;
    
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {    
    this.doSomething(changes.someInputData.currentValue);
}
```

The alternative is to use `getter`-`setter` approach like that

```
private _someInputData: string;

@Input() set someInputData(value: any) {
   this._someInputData = value;
   this.doSomething(this._someInputData);
}

get someInputData(): any {
    return this._someInputData;
}
```

Which approach is better? The short answer is I don't know :) I haven't measure performance difference, but:

- `ngOnChanges()` will allow you to compare current and prev value
- `ngOnChanges()` will track all inputs in comparison to `getter`-`setter` approach

However, there are some particular scenarios, usually with nested objects that tend to resist change detection in Angular, and for more elaborate solution see: [SOLUTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34796901/angular2-change-detection-ngonchanges-not-firing-for-nested-object)

**EDIT!**
Based on your comments, now I understand your problem, however I do not feel competent enough to tell you, why exactly such thing is occurring, it's related to the fact how Objects are made. Basically while passing Object through @Input decorator, you're creating a copy of object itself with all of its references. TLDR: Object passed by `@Input()` still holds a reference to memory that holds some variable. In that case what you need to do, is to create a deep copy of object and all of Objects within this object, because otherwise the nested references are still there. I see, that you're trying to mitigate this behaviour by using `Object.assign()`, which to my knowledge should work. However instead of doing so, please try using another approach:

```
const tempClone = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(productsData));
```

Comment: No actually its just the opposite.For e.g lets say cartItems = [{name:'',guide:''}]..When I pass it to child without modifying it...Now when I modify the data as shown in above images a property finalAmount is also added to the cartItems ....Now when I renavigate to this route the cartItems = [{name:'',guide:''}] should be this instead of [{finalAmount:5,name:'',guide:''}]

Comment: It is actually changing the parentData too...I doubt that the reference of the array still exists..But I try to remove this reference by cloning the array you can refer create-invoice.component.ts

Comment: Ideal Behavior should be whenever i refresh or renavigate to this route then the data passed from the parent must be reset and not with the changes I made before

Comment: @Snake_Eyes I've updated my answer, hope it'll help.

Comment: Yeah now you understand what i meant to say..I'll try what u r suggesting..Thanks for the reply

Comment: Hi @lemek, i tried your approach and it work...Also I've posted my answer too that I gathered from the internet. Might be useful for you too

Comment: I am happy to help :) Sometimes just a push into good direction is enough. Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `structuredClone()` to deep copy nested objects here in this case as my object having an array to a key

Refer the following screenshot as well:
[image]

Also JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(productsData)) has its own limitations

For more information refer these links:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/5344074/18480147
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/10916838/18480147