# At which point does ngOnChanges() gets fired

Tags: angular

What is the exact time when the ngOnChanges() method is called?

1. When value changes
2. When reference changes

Comment: It fires when the reference changes. This question will help clarify further for you on when ngOnChanges is run. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34796901/angular2-change-detection-ngonchanges-not-firing-for-nested-object?rq=2

Answer (score 2):

Angular fires `ngOnChanges` when it detects changes to the `@Input` properties of a Component. The method receives a `SimpeChanges` object, which contains the current and previous property values. You can iterate over the changed properties and use them according to your logic.

```
@Component({selector: 'my-cmp', template: `...`})
class MyComponent implements OnChanges {
  @Input() prop: number = 0;

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    // changes.prop contains the old and the new value...
  }
}
```

Every `@Input` property of your component gets a `SimpleChange` object (if the Property value changed)

`SimpleChanges` is an object that contains all the instance of these `SimpleChange` objects. You can access them by using the **name** of the `@Input` property as the key.

For example, if two `@Input` properties `message1` & `message2` were changed, then the `SimpleChanges` object will look like this:

```
{
  "message1": 
   {  "previousValue":"oldvalue",
      "currentValue":"newvalue",
      "firstChange":false 
   },
  "message2": 
   {  "previousValue":"oldvalue",
      "currentValue":"newvalue",
      "firstChange":false
   }
}
```

Hope this helps.