# Child Component does not detecting changes ,Alternate ways of ngDocheck to refresh componet value

Tags: angular, typescript, angular16

In the childComponent @input(), I am sending an array of objects on which the object has 3 properties **`name,id,selected(boolean)`**. I am changing the array selected property(true/false) only and passing to child component to plot values according to that. but it is not detecting changes.

if I am using ngdoCheck it is working fine but as ngDoCheck runs every time so i don't want to use to it.so is there any alternate solution is possible which is also efficient?

i have also tried to use ngOnchanges but it is not working as only value is changing not reference.

```
parent.ts

type model={
name:string,
id:int,
selected:boolean
}

public dataArray:model[]=[];

parent.html

  <child-component>
    *ngFor="let item of dataArray;"
    [item]="item"
  ></child-component>

child-component.ts

@Input() public item:model;

child-component.html

<h3>{{item | json}}</h3>
```

here if I am passing first time array child component is able to plot the values .but when i am mutating the array changes is not reflecting in child component.

For example i have two object

```
first time
[
{name:"item1",id:1,selected:false},{name:"item2",id:2,selected:false}]
]
after mutating
[
{name:"item1",id:1,selected:true}, // true is updatede
{name:"item2",id:2,selected:fasle}]
]
```

now after changing the array it is not detecting changes in child component

if I am using

> **ngDocheck**

then it is working fine but as it runs continuously that's why  i don't want to use it

Comment: Show code please. It's likely the `ChangeDetectionStrategy` in the tree of components is relevant here. `ngDoCheck` is only needed in specific circumstances, default change detection is almost always fine, if you're core is written appropriately

Comment: but is there any way to detect changes if same object is assining and then according to that update the dom

Comment: @AdamJenkins for your reference i have a array of objects and every object has children object which is of same type and if any object  is selected in the parent object or in child object then that array i am passing to child componet to update the dom .

type{
name:string
id:int,
children:[...parenttype
]
}

Comment: You need to post some code, preferably stripped down to a reproducible example

Comment: You already described the problem. You change value, but not reference. Handle accordingly.

Comment: @derstauner but any solution for that ?

Comment: what about ngOnChanges?

Comment: it is not detecting changes ihave tried that

Comment: @AdamJenkins I have posted sample example please have a look.

Comment: Satyam, that's not real code. As the answer has alluded to, it's very likely that you're mutating data when you shouldn't be, but because of angular's magic dirty checking, I can't be certain unless i see a real minimum reproducible example of the problem.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it Now it is resolved

Answer (score 1):

Everytime you have to update a property of one entry of your array, you will have to change the reference of the list.

i.e.

```js
// I don't know your data model, so for simplicity I created an inline type
yourUpdateMethod<T extends { id: string; propToUpdate: number}>(itemToUpdate: T, allElements: T[]) {
  // update your desired element
  itemToUpdate.propToUpdate *= 2;
  
  // Array.prototype.filter, once called will result in a new referenced array, so CD will be triggered as desired
  const updatedElements = allElements.filter((entry) => entry.id === itemToUpdate.id ? itemToUpdate : entry);

  // this needs to be passed to the child component
  return updatedElements;
}
```

Hope to helped you!

Answer (score 0):

In the above question when sending manipulated array or data from parent to child to ngOnchanges will not detect changes.

So to resolve this issue now i am assigning my changes in the array using spread operator

like this

```
this.dataArray=[...this.data]
```

for more information you can read this question [Angular2 change detection: ngOnChanges not firing for nested object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34796901/angular2-change-detection-ngonchanges-not-firing-for-nested-object)

Comment: Hi, changing the reference of the array was my suggestion. Could you please mark my answer as the resolving one? Thank you!